# How do Mockito matchers work?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Mockito argument matchers (such as `any`, `argThat`, `eq`, `same`, and `ArgumentCaptor.capture()`) behave very differently from Hamcrest matchers.

- Mockito matchers frequently cause InvalidUseOfMatchersException, even in code that executes long after any matchers were used.
- Mockito matchers are beholden to weird rules, such as only requiring the use of Mockito matchers for all arguments if one argument in a given method uses a matcher.
- Mockito matchers can cause NullPointerException when overriding `Answer`s or when using `(Integer) any()` etc.
- Refactoring code with Mockito matchers in certain ways can produce exceptions and unexpected behavior, and may fail entirely.

Why are Mockito matchers designed like this, and how are they implemented?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

[Mockito matchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) are static methods and calls to those methods, which *stand in for arguments* during calls to `when` and `verify`.

[Hamcrest matchers](http://web.archive.org/web/20140528033010/http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) (archived version) (or Hamcrest-style matchers) are stateless, general-purpose object instances that implement `Matcher<T>` and expose a method `matches(T)` that returns true if the object matches the Matcher's criteria. They are intended to be free of side effects, and are generally used in assertions such as the one below.

```
/* Mockito */  verify(foo).setPowerLevel(gt(9000));
/* Hamcrest */ assertThat(foo.getPowerLevel(), is(greaterThan(9000)));
```

Mockito matchers exist, separate from Hamcrest-style matchers, *so that descriptions of matching expressions fit directly into method invocations*: [Mockito matchers return `T` where Hamcrest matcher methods return Matcher objects (of type `Matcher<T>`).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351055/1426891)

Mockito matchers are invoked through static methods such as `eq`, `any`, `gt`, and `startsWith` on `org.mockito.Matchers` and `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers`. There are also adapters, which have changed across Mockito versions:

- For Mockito 1.x, `Matchers` featured some calls (such as `intThat` or `argThat`) are Mockito matchers that directly accept Hamcrest matchers as parameters. [`ArgumentMatcher<T>`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) extended `org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>`, which was used in the internal Hamcrest representation and was a *Hamcrest matcher base class* instead of any sort of Mockito matcher.
- For Mockito 2.0+, Mockito no longer has a direct dependency on Hamcrest. `Matchers` calls phrased as `intThat` or `argThat` wrap [`ArgumentMatcher<T>`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) objects that no longer implement `org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>` but are used in similar ways. Hamcrest adapters such as `argThat` and `intThat` are still available, but have moved to [`MockitoHamcrest`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html) instead.

Regardless of whether the matchers are Hamcrest or simply Hamcrest-style, they can be adapted like so:

```
/* Mockito matcher intThat adapting Hamcrest-style matcher is(greaterThan(...)) */
verify(foo).setPowerLevel(intThat(is(greaterThan(9000))));
```

In the above statement: `foo.setPowerLevel` is a method that accepts an `int`. `is(greaterThan(9000))` returns a `Matcher<Integer>`, which wouldn't work as a `setPowerLevel` argument. The Mockito matcher `intThat` wraps that Hamcrest-style Matcher and returns an `int` so it *can* appear as an argument; Mockito matchers like `gt(9000)` would wrap that entire expression into a single call, as in the first line of example code.

### What matchers do/return

```
when(foo.quux(3, 5)).thenReturn(true);
```

When not using argument matchers, Mockito records your argument values and compares them with their `equals` methods.

```
when(foo.quux(eq(3), eq(5))).thenReturn(true);    // same as above
when(foo.quux(anyInt(), gt(5))).thenReturn(true); // this one's different
```

When you call a matcher like `any` or `gt` (greater than), Mockito stores a matcher object that causes Mockito to skip that equality check and apply your match of choice. In the case of `argumentCaptor.capture()` it stores a matcher that saves its argument instead for later inspection.

Matchers return [dummy values](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/progress/HandyReturnValues.html) such as zero, empty collections, or `null`. Mockito tries to return a safe, appropriate dummy value, like 0 for `anyInt()` or `any(Integer.class)` or an empty `List<String>` for `anyListOf(String.class)`. Because of type erasure, though, Mockito lacks type information to return any value but `null` for `any()` or `argThat(...)`, which can cause a NullPointerException if trying to "auto-unbox" a `null` primitive value.

Matchers like `eq` and `gt` take parameter values; ideally, these values should be computed before the stubbing/verification starts. Calling a mock in the middle of mocking another call can interfere with stubbing.

Matcher methods can't be used as return values; there is no way to phrase `thenReturn(anyInt())` or `thenReturn(any(Foo.class))` in Mockito, for instance. Mockito needs to know exactly which instance to return in stubbing calls, and will not choose an arbitrary return value for you.

### Implementation details

Matchers are stored (as Hamcrest-style object matchers) in a stack contained in a class called [ArgumentMatcherStorage](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorage.java). MockitoCore and Matchers each own a [ThreadSafeMockingProgress](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ThreadSafeMockingProgress.java) instance, which *statically* contains a ThreadLocal holding MockingProgress instances. It's this [MockingProgressImpl](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/MockingProgressImpl.java) that holds a concrete [ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl.java). Consequently, mock and matcher state is static but thread-scoped consistently between the Mockito and Matchers classes.

Most matcher calls only add to this stack, with an exception for matchers like [`and`, `or`, and `not`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html). This perfectly corresponds to (and relies on) the [evaluation order of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800590/1426891), which evaluates arguments left-to-right before invoking a method:

```
when(foo.quux(anyInt(), and(gt(10), lt(20)))).thenReturn(true);
[6]      [5]  [1]       [4] [2]     [3]
```

This will:

1. Add `anyInt()` to the stack.
2. Add `gt(10)` to the stack.
3. Add `lt(20)` to the stack.
4. Remove `gt(10)` and `lt(20)` and add `and(gt(10), lt(20))`.
5. Call `foo.quux(0, 0)`, which (unless otherwise stubbed) returns the default value `false`. Internally Mockito marks `quux(int, int)` as the most recent call.
6. Call `when(false)`, which discards its argument and prepares to stub method `quux(int, int)` identified in 5. The only two valid states are with stack length 0 (equality) or 2 (matchers), and there are two matchers on the stack (steps 1 and 4), so Mockito stubs the method with an `any()` matcher for its first argument and `and(gt(10), lt(20))` for its second argument and clears the stack.

This demonstrates a few rules:

- Mockito can't tell the difference between `quux(anyInt(), 0)` and `quux(0, anyInt())`. They both look like a call to `quux(0, 0)` with one int matcher on the stack. Consequently, if you use one matcher, you have to match all arguments.
- Call order isn't just important, it's *what makes this all work*. Extracting matchers to variables generally doesn't work, because it usually changes the call order. Extracting matchers to methods, however, works great.

  ```
  int between10And20 = and(gt(10), lt(20));
  /* BAD */ when(foo.quux(anyInt(), between10And20)).thenReturn(true);
  // Mockito sees the stack as the opposite: and(gt(10), lt(20)), anyInt().

  public static int anyIntBetween10And20() { return and(gt(10), lt(20)); }
  /* OK */  when(foo.quux(anyInt(), anyIntBetween10And20())).thenReturn(true);
  // The helper method calls the matcher methods in the right order.
  ```
- The stack changes often enough that Mockito can't police it very carefully. It can only check the stack when you interact with Mockito or a mock, and has to accept matchers without knowing whether they're used immediately or abandoned accidentally. In theory, the stack should always be empty outside of a call to `when` or `verify`, but Mockito can't check that automatically.
  You can check manually with `Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`.
- In a call to `when`, Mockito actually calls the method in question, which will throw an exception if you've stubbed the method to throw an exception (or require non-zero or non-null values).
  `doReturn` and `doAnswer` (etc) do *not* invoke the actual method and are often a useful alternative.
- If you had called a mock method in the middle of stubbing (e.g. to calculate an answer for an `eq` matcher), Mockito would check the stack length against *that* call instead, and likely fail.
- If you try to do something bad, like [stubbing/verifying a final method](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito), Mockito will call the real method *and also leave extra matchers on the stack*. The `final` method call may not throw an exception, but you may get an [InvalidUseOfMatchersException](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter.java#L231) from the stray matchers when you next interact with a mock.

### Common problems

- **[InvalidUseOfMatchersException](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter.java#L231)**:

  - Check that every single argument has exactly one matcher call, if you use matchers at all, and that you haven't used a matcher outside of a `when` or `verify` call. Matchers should never be used as stubbed return values or fields/variables.
  - Check that you're not calling a mock as a part of providing a matcher argument.
  - Check that you're not trying to stub/verify a final method with a matcher. It's a great way to leave a matcher on the stack, and unless your final method throws an exception, this might be the only time you realize the method you're mocking is final.
- **NullPointerException with primitive arguments:** `(Integer) any()` returns null while `any(Integer.class)` returns 0; this can cause a `NullPointerException` if you're expecting an `int` instead of an Integer. In any case, prefer `anyInt()`, which will return zero and also skip the auto-boxing step.
- **NullPointerException or other exceptions:** Calls to `when(foo.bar(any())).thenReturn(baz)` will actually *call* `foo.bar(null)`, which you might have stubbed to throw an exception when receiving a null argument. Switching to `doReturn(baz).when(foo).bar(any())` [skips the stubbed behavior](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

### General troubleshooting

- Use [MockitoJUnitRunner](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html), or explicitly call [`validateMockitoUsage`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage()) in your `tearDown` or `@After` method (which the runner would do for you automatically). This will help determine whether you've misused matchers.
- For debugging purposes, add calls to `validateMockitoUsage` in your code directly. This will throw if you have anything on the stack, which is a good warning of a bad symptom.

Comment: Thanks for this writeup. A NullPointerException with the when/thenReturn format was causing me problems, until I changed it to doReturn/when.

Comment: this helped me in particular:  "Matcher methods can't be used as return values; there is no way to phrase thenReturn(anyInt()) or thenReturn(any(Foo.class))"

Comment: Jeff, this is a fantastic answer, and for me, it's worth returning back to over and over, even though I have a pretty good handle on the topic.  I upvoted this answer years ago.  But re-reading it, I think there might be a very small error in it.  In the second bullet point near the top, you mention that Mockito 2.0+ drops the dependency on Hamcrest.  I'm reasonably sure that this change actually happened with Mockito 2.1.0, not 2.0.0.  Maybe you'd consider checking this and editing it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thank you for the compliment! This one is tricky: Mockito 2.0 went through [111 release candidates but never saw a non-beta release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core), so publicly 1.10.19 and 2.1.0 are adjacent. That said, the change to a provided dependency is a part of the [upgrade to Hamcrest 1.3](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/commit/4b3de2aee1860ecaa01d8fa36847211a2b4472f5) in [2.0.26-beta](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.0.26-beta/build.gradle#L61) documented in 2.0.24-beta as a 2.0 feature. It's still "2.0+" ("2.0.26-beta+").

Comment: Oh, wow, OK.  I never realised that 2.0 didn't get out of beta.  Please accept my apologies for my incorrect "correction".

Answer (score 13):

Just a small addition to Jeff Bowman's excellent answer, as I found this question when searching for a solution to one of my own problems:

If a call to a method matches more than one mock's `when` trained calls, the order of the `when` calls is important, and should be from the most wider to the most specific. Starting from one of Jeff's examples:

```
when(foo.quux(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(true);
when(foo.quux(anyInt(), eq(5))).thenReturn(false);
```

is the order that ensures the (probably) desired result:

```
foo.quux(3 /*any int*/, 8 /*any other int than 5*/) //returns true
foo.quux(2 /*any int*/, 5) //returns false
```

If you inverse the when calls then the result would always be `true`.

Comment: Though this is useful information, it regards [stubbing, not matchers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20104664/1426891), so it may not make sense on this question. Order does matter, but only in that *the last-defined matching chain wins*: This means coexisting stubs are often declared most-specific to least, but in some cases you may want a very broad override of specifically-mocked behavior in a single test case, at which point a broad definition may need to come last.

Comment: @JeffBowman I thought that it makes sense on this question since the question is about mockito matchers and matchers can be used when stubbing (as in most of your examples). Since searching google for an explanation got me to this question I think it's useful to have this information here.

Comment: its useful and related as a matcher is desired and supposed to have an effect. giving reasons why a matcher wont have an effect for a certain application case is making you understand how matchers are (or arent) applied during code execution. such a stub often bundles matchers. thus having competing stubs also means having a "hidden" competition of matchers going on there under the hood. its about how to make the matcher (and thus you) going to win.

Comment: in a very simplified view a stub is a "list of matchers" where the list might be realized via a stack or whatever else you like to have.