# Using mockito.when without knowing the parameters of the method call

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm Junit testing a class and had to create some Mockito mock objects. The line of code I'm interested in is this

```
Mockito.when(emailer.sendEmail(INPUT GOES HERE)).thenReturn(true);
```

the sendEmail() method of emailer takes in two parameters, and I'm not sure what they will be. Is there a sort of wild card that can be used there to replace the parameters without knowing what they will be?

Comment: One of the `Mockito.any...()`.

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html Check section 3, Argument matchers.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the question comments.

- `Matchers.any(ClassName.class)`, which is usually what you want. In Mockito 1.x, this stands in for any object, regardless of its type, but by receiving a class it will typically avoid the need for a cast. (According to Mockito contributor [Brice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48136/brice) in an SO [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55631479), this behavior will change in Mockito 2 and beyond, presumably to behave more like `isA` as `any(MyClass.class)` would suggest in English.)
- `Matchers.any()`, which will usually require a cast, and isn't a good idea for primitives.
- `Matchers.anyInt()` or `Matchers.anyShort()` (etc), which are good for primitives.
- `Matchers.anyString()`, because Strings are a common use-case.

Because `Mockito` extends `Matchers`, most of these methods will be available on `Mockito`, but some IDEs have trouble finding static methods across subclasses. You can find all of them by using `import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;`.

Read more about all of the matchers available to you at the [org.mockito.Matchers documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html).

If you run into trouble, or want to learn more about how these wildcards work under the surface, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).