# Misplaced argument matcher detected here. You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Out of the following two test cases in **BundleProcessorTest.java**, i am getting below exception, although, my first test case passes successfully.

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at bundle.test.BundleProcessorTest.bundlePluginShouldNotBeNull(BundleProcessorTest.java:22)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>       when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>       verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
>
> at
>   bundle.test.BundleProcessorTest.bundlePluginCollectionShouldNotBeNull(BundleProcessorTest.java:28)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Please find below simplified code listing :-

**BundlePlugin.java**

```
package bundle;

import java.util.List;

public class BundlePlugin {

    private final String pluginName ;
    private final List<String> featureContent ;

    public BundlePlugin(String pluginName, List<String> featureContent) {
        super();
        this.pluginName = pluginName;
        this.featureContent = featureContent;
    }

    public String getPluginName() {
        return pluginName;
    }

    public List<String> getFeatureContent() {
        return featureContent;
    }
}
```

**BundleProcessor.java**

```
package bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BundleProcessor {

    public BundlePlugin getBundlePlugin(String pluginName, Iterator<String> artifactIterator) {

        List<String> featureContent = new ArrayList<String>() ;

        return new BundlePlugin(pluginName, featureContent);
    }
}
```

**BundleProcessorTest.java**

```
package bundle.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import bundle.BundleProcessor;

public class BundleProcessorTest {

    BundleProcessor bundleProcessor = new BundleProcessor() ;   

    @Test
    public void bundlePluginShouldNotBeNull() {

        Iterator<String> artifactIterator = mock(Iterator.class) ;
        bundle.BundlePlugin bundlePlugin = bundleProcessor.getBundlePlugin(anyString(), artifactIterator) ;
        assertNotNull( bundlePlugin );
    }

    @Test
    public void bundlePluginContentShouldNotBeNull() {
        Iterator<String> artifactIterator = mock(Iterator.class) ;
        bundle.BundlePlugin bundlePlugin = bundleProcessor.getBundlePlugin(anyString(), artifactIterator) ;

        List<String> featureContent = bundlePlugin.getFeatureContent() ;
        assertNotNull( featureContent );
    }
}
```

How to execute this test without problem.

---

**Edit 1:**

But if i mark the **bundlePluginCollectionShouldNotBeNull** test with @Ignore annotation, then first test case passes without any exception.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are using mockito `anyString()` while calling the test method, it should be used only for verifying a mock object to ensure a certain method is called with any string parameter inside the test, but not to invoke the test itself. For your test use empty string `""` instead to `anyString()`.

Comment: @ user3560660: But if i mark the bundlePluginCollectionShouldNotBeNull test with @Ignore annotation, then first test case passes without any exception.

Comment: Not sure why `@Ignore` on one allows the other to work but the answer is correct. You cannot use `anyString()` outside a `Mockito` stub or verify method. Use any actual string you want.

Comment: @John B: Even if you delete, any of the test case. Other test case will work.

Comment: I suggest you quit trying to figure out why it works in odd cases and stop using outside how it was intended to be used. Trying to figure out why it doesn't fail in one case and does in the other is without real value. Just pass a read String.

Comment: @rits Mockito doesn't have a verify "mode", so if both tests are run, mockito thinks that the `anyString()` is related to the `bundlePluginShouldNotBeNull` test. Using MockitoJUnitRunner may catch this problem and/or give you a better error message.

Comment: @NamshubWriter: Executing test cases with MockitoJUnitRunner clearly specifies, that the problem is with the verify call. Upvoted your comment :). But, I still don't understand, why, the problem goes undetected with default runner.

Comment: `MockitoJUnitRunner` adds an `@After` method that calls [`Mockito.validateMockitoUsage`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage%28%29). With the normal runner, JUnit ends the test in an invalid state but cannot detect it. I put more details [in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

Answer (score 4):

Ideally `anyString()` should not be used outside the mock or verify block. I was facing the same issue.Changing the `anyString()` to some string ("xyz") value works fine.

**Note :** Make a note that you might use `anyString()` to some other methods that leads in failure of some other method. It wasted my one hour to figure it out. My actual test method was getting passes individually but when i was trying to run that in a hole it was getting failed because of the reason that some other test case was using `anyString()` outside to mock or verify block.

Answer (score 1):

We need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:

mock-maker-inline

please refer article https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@Mock` and getting this same error, it might be due to mocks not functioning properly. For me, adding `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in `setup()` resolved the error.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, Should use `@Spy` annotation with `@InjectMocks` annotation.

Comment: When answering an old question having an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23273634/5698098) please ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to it. This answer currently does not explain how using `@Spy` with `@InjectMocks` solves OP's question. Please elobrate your answer to make it clear how it answers OP's question.