# How can I stub Long.valueOf(String) in Mockito?

Tags: mocking, mockito

I have:

```
when(Long.valueOf(anyString())).thenReturn(anyLong());
```

It gets a `NumberFormatException` on `Long.valueOf(String)` because "" is being passed in.

The code I'm testing is this:

```
 final Long id = Long.valueOf(foo.bar());
```

How can I get around that?

Comment: Can you show some more context please?

Comment: It seems like an odd thing to mock and on top of that I don't think mockito can mock static method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I edited my post with more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This request is a bad idea.

1. You can't use `anyLong()` as a return value. [Mockito matchers only stand in for argument values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work) Mockito needs to know exactly what value to return, but you can pick an arbitrary one.
2. You can't stub static methods using Mockito. You can only stub *object instances*, because Mockito needs to be able to replace the implementation with its own. You can use Powermock to stub static methods, [as listed in the Powermock documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method); Powermock uses class rewriting to secretly replace the class to stub (`Long` here).
3. Even if you could replace `Long.valueOf` easily, it wouldn't make much sense. Imagine debugging code when `Long.valueOf("5")` returns 7.

My recommendation is to use an object that represents what you're trying to do, then mock that.

```
class SystemUnderTest {
  class IdExtractor {
    long extractIdFromString(String string) {
      return Long.valueOf(string);
    }
  }

  IdExtractor idExtractor = new IdExtractor();

  public boolean reticulateSplines(String input) {
    long id = idExtractor.extractIdFromString(input);
    // ...
  }
}

@Test public void reticulateSplinesShouldWork() {
  SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
  IdExtractor mockIdExtractor = mock(SystemUnderTest.IdExtractor.class);
  systemUnderTest.idExtractor = mockIdExtractor;

  when(mockIdExtractor.extractIdFromString(anyString())).thenReturn(42L);
  assertTrue(systemUnderTest.reticulateSplines("blah"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by using [org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html), which states:

> ReflectionTestUtils is a collection of reflection-based utility
> methods for use in unit and integration testing scenarios.

In your case, the solution might be:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(targetObject, "foo.bar().equivalent", "stringValueHere");
```