# Mockito.when() not working

Tags: mockito, guava

I am trying to mock a call to a protected method of one of my classes:

```java
import com.couchbase.client.java.view.Stale; // an enum
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class MyClass {
  public List<String> myList(Optional<Integer> arg1, Optional<Stale> arg2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The mock shall be accomplished in the following way:

```java
// Providing types for any() does not change anything
Mockito.when(myClass.myList(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).thenReturn(new ArrayList());
```

Whenever the previous line is executed the actual `myList()` method is called with null values for `arg1` and `arg2`. Why is the method called, at all? After all, I am trying to avoid any executing thereof...

Comment: How do you create the mock object?

Comment: Can you confirm that the class or the method are not `final` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brice mentioned, if your `myList` method is final, then Java skips virtual method dispatch and will call the original object (not your mock).

If you are *spying* on an actual class, it is expected behavior that `when` will call the actual object as part of the stub: after all, in the expression `when(foo.bar())` Java doesn't know anything special about `when` and assumes that it cares about the *return value*) of `foo.bar()`, not the call itself. (I walk through the stubbing process in the "Implementation details" section of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891).)

This syntax is better for spies:

```
doReturn(new ArrayList()).when(myClass).myList(any(), any());
```

Because this different `when` method receives an object, Mockito can prepare the object to *do nothing during the stubbing*, which avoids any spurious calls to your `myList` method.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jeff's answer did not show a workaround for my problem it pointed me into the right direction.

After changing the mocking behaviour to `doReturn...` I suddenly got an error message. This message told me that `myClass` is not a mock which makes sense since you can only mock (or stub?) methods of mocked or spied objects. So as Jeff's answer indicates and is explained in the [documentation of mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) I created a partial mock of `MyClass` with

```java
MyClass myClass = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());
```

With this partial mock Jeff's approach to method mocking suddenly worked (mine still does not and should therefore be avoided).

So: Thank you, Jeff!