# Use Mockito 2.0.7 to mock lambda expressions

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, lambda, mockito

I want to mock a query provided on my repository like this:

```
@Test
public void GetByEmailSuccessful() {
    // setup mocks
    Mockito.when(this.personRepo.findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> (p.getEmail().equals(Mockito.any(String.class))))
            .findFirst()
            .get())
            .thenReturn(this.personOut);
    Mockito.when(this.communityUserRepo.findOne(this.communityUserId))
            .thenReturn(this.communityUserOut);
...
```

My `@Before` method looks like this:

```
@Before
public void initializeMocks() throws Exception {
    // prepare test data.
    this.PrepareTestData();

    // init mocked repos.
    this.personRepo = Mockito.mock(IPersonRepository.class);
    this.communityUserRepo = Mockito.mock(ICommunityUserRepository.class);
    this.userProfileRepo = Mockito.mock(IUserProfileRepository.class);
}
```

Sadly when I run the test I receive the error:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

When I double-click the error it points at the `.get()` method of the first lambda.

Have any of you successfully mocked a lambda expression and know how I can solve my problem?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you must specify a return value for `personRepo.findAll()` first, and then subsequently for all method invocations.

Comment: I have the bad feeling that you want to test mockito instead of testing your code. What is the code of getByEmail()? What should it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to mock such deep calls.  Simply mock `personRepo.findAll()` and let the Streaming API work as normal:

```
Person person1 = ...
Person person2 = ...
Person person3 = ...
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, ...);
when(personRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(people);
```

And then instead of

`.filter( p -> (p.getEmail().equals(Mockito.any(String.class))) )`

just set/mock `email` on your `Person` objects to be the expected value.

Alternatively, consider implementing `PersonRepo.findByEmail`.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

```
Mockito.when(this.personRepo.findAll()
      .stream()
      .filter(p -> (p.getEmail().equals(Mockito.any(String.class))))
      .findFirst()
      .get())
    .thenReturn(this.personOut);
```

First, you're trying to mock a chain of five different method calls. Mockito doesn't handle this very well; though the [`RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) (if put on personRepo) would save and return stub objects where applicable, each call to `when` will itself stub exactly one call.

Second, Mockito matchers aren't flexible enough to work deeply in calls; calls to `when` should contain exactly one method call without chaining, and calls to Mockito matchers like `any` should [stand in for exactly one of the arguments in that method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). The way you have it, you're creating a predicate `p -> (p.getEmail().equals(null))` and leaving a matcher on the stack to break things later.

Use [Alex Wittig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084462/1426891) to solve this problem, and be mindful of stubbing and using matchers correctly in future problems.