# Use Mockito to write stub for Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, mockito, powermockito

I have a method where I am using Java 8 lambda expression. While writing unit test for this method I need to write stub for that expression. How we can write that?

```
public List<User> methodA(String userId) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
    List<User> usersFilterByUserId = users.stream().filter(u -> u.getUserid().equalsIgnoreCase(userId)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    some other stuff ....
}
```

I tried solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081357/use-mockito-2-0-7-to-mock-lambda-expressions) as -

```
@Test
public void testMethodA() {
    ArrayList<User> mockUsers = mock(ArrayList.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ArrayList.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockUsers);
    User user = mock(User.class);
    Iterable<User> mockIt = mock(Iterable.class);
    when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(mockIt);
    doNothing().when(mockIt).forEach(any());

    // This gives compiler error which is obvious 
    // The method thenReturn(Stream<User>) in the type 
    // OngoingStubbing<Stream<User>> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<User>)
    ArrayList<User> mockUsersFilterByUserId = mock(ArrayList.class);
    when(mockUsers.stream()).thenReturn(mockUsersFilterByUserId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to do - you're trying to mock all of the local variables, so it's possible you don't fully understand the goal of mocking.  But `stream()` returns a `Stream`, not an `ArrayList`, so that's your proximate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you mock everything in your unit test.
The test becomes complex and loose its value.

In `methodA`, the single thing that you should mock is the dependency  :

```
userRepository.findAll().
```

By mocking the invocation to this method, you will by side effect use mocked data in the lambda body as it uses the result of `findAll()`.

```
List<User> usersByMock = new ArrayList<>();
usersByMock.add(...);
usersByMock.add(...);
usersByMock.add(...);
...
when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(usersByMock);
```

Comment: Did you mean no need to stub lambda expression? Have the actual interaction in place.

Comment: Sure. lambda expression is just syntactic sugar. You could replace it by a classic for loop.