# How to mock lambda expression anymatch return object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a java method which uses lambda expression to match a value.

I want to test the condition for both true and false.

```
employee.getAppraisals().stream().anyMatch(appraisal::isPromoted)
```

And i tried to use the code below to create the mockito unit test but it never works. The link i followed is : [Use Mockito 2.0.7 to mock lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081357/use-mockito-2-0-7-to-mock-lambda-expressions)

```
Mockito.when(employee.getAppraisals()
      .stream()
      ..anyMatch(p->p.equals(Mockito.any()))).thenReturn(true)
```

But i dont know how to mock Promotion object to return its bean proeprty value of promotion.isPromoted as true using mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to mock the whole stream() chain.

You want to mock two things here, `getAppraisals()` which will return a collection of `mock(Appraisal.class)`.

These Appraisal mocks will then answer to the method call for `isPromoted()`.