# Junit testing or mocking call to ThreadPoolExecutor's submit method , passing lambda expression

Tags: mockito, junit4, junit5, powermockito

I have a statement shown below which i need to test/verify call to:

```
snmpDispatchDelegateExecutor.submit(() -> processRunFunctionException(exception));
```

now it contains many things at once (Async calls , lambda and private methods all in one ), so i have some questions :
1: for handling submit() call which return future tasks.
do i have to do something like

```
when(snmpDispatchDelegateExecutorMock.submit(any()/Runnable)).thenReturn(any()/FutureTask).
```

then the problem is how to achieve it (creating Runnable and Future). Tried creating both looks complex .

2: processRunFunctionException(exception) is a private method ,do we need to cover that , lot of "SO" posts says no need to cover private methods . In general if i focus on covering public methods private method should get covered as well . referred [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods)

3: How to work with lambda expression here . went through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081357/use-mockito-2-0-7-to-mock-lambda-expressions) but no much help.

Answer (score 0):

It's often problematic to mock classes that you don't own, since you are hard-coding behavior in your test that may not match the actual behavior.

I suggest using a real `ExecutorService` implementation. For instance, you can use an implementation that does its work in the current thread (see [Is there an ExecutorService that uses the current thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread/14639686#14639686)) or an implementation that only does the work when you tell it to.