# Mockito - You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing - have tried many things but still no solution

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I have the following piece of code:

> ```
> PowerMockito.mockStatic(DateUtils.class);      
> //And this is the line which does the exception - notice it's a static function  
> PowerMockito.when(DateUtils.isEqualByDateTime (any(Date.class),any(Date.class)).thenReturn(false);
> ```

The class begins with:
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({CM9DateUtils.class,DateUtils.class})`

And I get **org.Mockito.exceptions.InvalidUseOfMatchersException...... You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.....** (The error appears twice in the Failure Trace - but both point to the same line)

In other places in my code the usage of *when* is done and it's working properly. Also, when debugging my code I found that any(Date.class) returns null.

I have tried the following solutions which I saw other people found useful, but for me it doesn't work:

1. Adding

   `@After
   public void checkMockito() {
   Mockito.validateMockitoUsage(); 
   }`
   **or**
   `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`
   **or**
   `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
2. Change to 

   `PowerMockito.when(new Boolean(DateUtils.isEqualByDateTime(any(Date.class), any(Date.class)))).thenReturn(false);`
3. Using `anyObject()` (it doesn't compile)
4. Using 
   `notNull(Date.class)`  **or**  `(Date)notNull()`
5. Replace
   `when(........).thenReturn(false);`

   with
   `Boolean falseBool=new Boolean(false);`
   and
   `when(.......).thenReturn(falseBool);`

Comment: Without a testable example, and noting the clarification mentioned below as a comment, I don't think this question has enough detail to be answerable or useful to future readers. Please consider adding more detail. (Note that Mockito matchers carry state, so you can get similar exceptions simply by trying to 'save matcher values' to local variables, and Mockito will not tell you this until a stubbing/verification call much later. Posting your surrounding code is crucial to diagnose matcher problems.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end,what worked for me was to export the line that does the exception to some other static function. I called it *compareDates*.

**My implementation:**

In the class that is tested (e.g - *MyClass*)
`static boolean compareDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
        return DateUtils.isEqualByDateTime (date1, date2);
    }`

and in the test class:
`PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
PowerMockito.when(MyClass.compareDates(any(Date.class), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(false);`

Unfortunately I can't say I fully understand why this solution works and the previous didn't.
 maybe it has to do with the fact that *DateUtils* class is not my code, and I can't access it's source, only the generated *.class* file, but i'm really not sure about it.

---

**EDIT**

The above solution was just a workaround that did not solve the need to cover the         `DateUtils` *isEqualByDateTime* call in the code.
What **actually** solved the real problem was to import the `DateUtils` class which has the actual implementation and not the one that just extends it, which was what I imported before.

After doing this I could use the original line

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(DateUtils.class);      

PowerMockito.when(DateUtils.isEqualByDateTime (any(Date.class),any(Date.class)).thenReturn(false);
```

without any exception.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed on the [PowerMockito Getting Started Page](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method), you'll need to use *both the PowerMock runner as well as the `@PrepareForTest` annotation*.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DateUtils.class)
```

Ensure that you're using the @RunWith annotation that comes with JUnit 4, `org.junit.runner.RunWith`. Because it's always accepted a `value` attribute, it's pretty odd to me that you're receiving that error if you're using the correct RunWith type.

`any(Date.class)` is correct to return `null`: Rather than using a magic "matches any Date" instance, Mockito uses [a hidden stack of matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891) to track which matcher expressions correspond to matched arguments, and returns `null` for Objects (and 0 for integers, and false for booleans, and so forth).

Comment: Ok, so seems I forgot to import the "RunWith", but still, after importing it and getting over the compilation error,  still I get the same exception.

Comment: Also, I did not mention it in the original post (now edited), but this @PrepareForTest(DateUtils.class) is used in my code

Answer (score 0):

### I had a similar problem with  **TextUtils** in my Kotlin Test Class

```
PowerMockito.`when`(TextUtils.isEmpty(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true)
```

Resolved it by adding below code on top of my Test Class

```
 @PrepareForTest(TextUtils::class)
```

and called *mockStatic* this before *PowerMockito.`when`*

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils::class.java)
```