# Getting InvalidUseOfMatchersException from call to verify() even though all arguements are of type 'Matchers'

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code in a test which uses the Mockito framework to verify that the method `drawTextOnCanvas()` was called with the correct parameters.

```
    // The two objects below are mocks.  The rest of the objects used in
    // the call to verify() are plain old java objects I've instantiated elsewhere.
    BufferedImage testImage = Mockito.mock(BufferedImage.class);
    Mockito.when(testImage.getHeight()).thenReturn(10);

    Graphics mockGraphics = Mockito.mock(Graphics.class);
    Mockito.when(mockGraphics.getFontMetrics(Matchers.any(Font.class)))
            .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(FontMetrics.class));


    Mockito.verify(drawingUtil).drawTextOnCanvas(
            Matchers.eq(imageCategory.getWidth()), 
            Matchers.eq(mockGraphics),
            Matchers.any(Font.class), 
            Matchers.eq(Arrays.asList("Test text")),
            Matchers.eq(testImage.getHeight() + 10),
            Matchers.any(FontMetrics.class), 
            Matchers.eq(10));
```

However it throws the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 4 recorded:
-> at com.test.package(ExampleTest.java:66)
-> at com.test.package(ExampleTest.java:67)
-> at com.test.package(ExampleTest.java:67)
-> at com.test.package(ExampleTest.java:68)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class........
```

I have however discovered that if I replace the line

```
 Matchers.eq(testImage.getHeight() + 10),
```

with

```
 Matchers.eq(someInteger),
```

the test runs with no exceptions, which is what puzzles me.

I've looked at the JavaDoc for Matchers and as far as I can see what I've written should work, unless there is some rule about putting calls to mock objects inside a call to `eq()` that I've missed.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue which got resolved when I returned an actual object instead of using a Matcher.
For me even this was returning InvalidUseOfMatchersException even though I was using Matchers in all arguments.

when(lookupService.someMethod(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(any(CustomObject.class));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've nailed it: You've mocked `testImage`, and calling a mock method while stubbing is not allowed. The documentation is not clear on that limitation.

I wrote [an exhaustive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891) on Mockito matchers before (see "implementation details"), but the short version is that *Mockito keeps its argument matchers on a stack* and that every call to a mocked *n*-argument method checks that the stack contains exactly 0 or *n* matchers.

```
Mockito.verify(drawingUtil).drawTextOnCanvas(
        Matchers.eq(imageCategory.getWidth()),      // A1
        Matchers.eq(mockGraphics),                  // A2
        Matchers.any(Font.class),                   // A3
        Matchers.eq(Arrays.asList("Test text")),    // A4
        Matchers.eq(testImage.getHeight() + 10),    // B
        Matchers.any(FontMetrics.class),            // C1
        Matchers.eq(10));                           // C2
```

The call order is something like this: After `verify(drawingUtil)`, Java prepares the arguments to `drawTextOnCanvas` in order, calling A1 through A4. Suddenly the call to B happens, and Mockito prepares as if `textImage.getHeight()` were embedded within a `when(...)` call. There are 4 matchers on the stack, and Mockito expects either to match by equality (zero matchers) or the number of arguments to `getHeight()` (also zero matchers). Mockito throws that exception with that "4 matchers recorded" message before even getting to C1, C2, or `drawTextOnCanvas`.

As a matter of good practice, extract all `Matchers.eq` values (that contain method calls) to local variables, with a particular emphasis on calls to mocked objects.