# Mockito NullPointerException on Native Query

Tags: java, mockito

I am having a problem on my query object, it becomes null even though I stub it with a query mock object..
This is the code

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryString, SomeRandom.class);

return query.getResultList(); //-->This is where I get the error, the query object is null.
```

my Test method is

```
Query query = mock(Query.class);
when(entityManager.createNativeQuery("", SomeRandom.class)).thenReturn(query);
List<SomeRandom> someList = requestDao.getSomeList(parameter, parameter, parameter, parameter);
```

Comment: Have you tried _anyString()_ instead of empty string ("") when mocking the _createNativeQuery_ function?

Comment: yes I did, but I already solved the problem. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably means that one of the matchers that you passed to the mocked method did not match. You passed an actual `String` instance (the empty string), which is transformed under the hood into an [Equals matcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/internal/matchers/Equals.html). Your example would only work if `queryString` was the empty string as well.

This should match on any query string:

```
when(entityManager.createNativeQuery(anyString(), eq(SomeRandom.class)))
  .thenReturn(query);
```

And this on some concrete String that you expect to be passed:

```
String expectedQueryString = "select 1";

when(entityManager.createNativeQuery(expectedQueryString, SomeRandom.class))
  .thenReturn(query);
```

**Edit based on comment:**

If changing from `eq(SomeRandom.class)` to `any()` solved the problem, then the `eq(SomeRandom.class)` matcher did not match, which means `SomeRandom.class` was not what was in fact passed to the mocked method.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I already did that thing before posting this question. I got the answer from this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/SimpleJpaQueryUnitTests.java

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with this code, I used 
[This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/SimpleJpaQueryUnitTests.java) as my reference.

```
Class<?> type = Mockito.any();
when(entityManager.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString(), type)).thenReturn(query);
```

Comment: **Never extract Mockito matchers to local variables.** [Matchers work via side-effects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), and extracting like you have here gets them misaligned. This code works for now (as `any` doesn't check anything about the parameter) but this will break in hard-to-diagnose ways if you change either matcher to `eq` or anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check it out.