# Mockito Null Pointer Exception and Unfinished stubbing detected

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to unit test a `service` with `entityManager`

**Service code to be Mocked:**

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);

Object[] object = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
```

**Test Code Mocking:**

```
when(entityManagerMock.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString()).getSingleResult()).thenReturn(fixture);
```

This results in Null Pointer Exception

However since `Mockito.anyString()` returns empty string by default `createNativeQuery` might not be expecting it. So changed to below.

```
doReturn(fixture).when(entityManagerMock.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString()).getSingleResult());
```

but with this I get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.novartis.idot.service.SrapiSapMeetingServiceTest.testFindById(SrapiSapMeetingServiceTest.java:112)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

I am expecting this is due to the fact I am calling `createNativeQuery` inside `when` but then I can't mock `query` separately. How do I mock?

Comment: This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343646/mockito-nullpointerexception-on-native-query

Answer (score 1):

Please correct to:

```
Query mockedQuery = mock(Query.class); //!
when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(fixture); //!! ;)
when(entityManagerMock.createNativeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
```

I hope this explains, where the `null` and "Unfinished stubbing" originates. (you have to mock any object/call "in between")

---

This ^ refers only to "code to be mocked" and assumes no "other issues" (e.g. `entityMangerMock != null`)

Answer (score 0):

when(entityManagerMock.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString()).getSingleResult()).thenReturn(fixture);

if entity manager is a mock then you can't cross several methods because by default all methods for a mock return null, you should do it in two steps:

```
    Query queryMock = Mockito.mock(Query.class);    
 when(entityManagerMock.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(queryMock);
    when(queryMock.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(fixture);
```

Hope that this will be useful!