# Why does Mockito "when" work on a non-mock object?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I recently saw some Mockito 1.9.5 code that worked like this:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
...
Mockito.when(myObject.someMethod()).thenReturn("bogus");
```

Since myObject is **not** a mock object, but is an instance of a non-mocked class, I was surprised this compiled and ran without failing the unit test.  I expected I would get a failure saying something like "You asked me to set up an expectation on a non-mock object, and I expected to set expectations only on mock objects."

Why doesn't this code cause a test failure?

---

**Update:** adding more code that is necessary to actually replicate the behavior I find confusing. These examples fully illustrate my question.  The following code behaves as I expected--when I run this test the test **fails** with a message that

> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

```
public class AnotherObject{
    public String doSomething(){
        return "did something";
    };
}

public class MyObject{
    private AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();

    public void setAnotherObject(AnotherObject anotherObject) {
        this.anotherObject = anotherObject;
    }

    public String someMethod(){
        return anotherObject.doSomething();
    }
}

@Test
public void WhyDoesWhenWorkOnNonMock() throws Exception {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    Mockito.when(myObject.someMethod()).thenReturn("bogus");
}
```

Now if I add a couple specific lines to this contrived test, **the test no longer fails** even though I expected the same failure and same message as before:

```
public class AnotherObject{
    public String doSomething(){
        return "did something";
    };
}

public class MyObject{
    private AnotherObject anotherObject = new AnotherObject();

    public void setAnotherObject(AnotherObject anotherObject) {
        this.anotherObject = anotherObject;
    }

    public String someMethod(){
        return anotherObject.doSomething();
    }
}

@Test
public void WhyDoesWhenWorkOnNonMock() throws Exception {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    AnotherObject mockAnotherObject = Mockito.mock(AnotherObject.class);
    myObject.setAnotherObject(mockAnotherObject);
    Mockito.when(myObject.someMethod()).thenReturn("bogus");
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By incredible and fragile coincidence, probably, unless `myObject` was actually set to be a spy.

Mockito allows for the creation of a "spy" of a real object:

```
MyObject myObject = spy(new MyObject());
Mockito.when(myObject.someMethod()).thenReturn("something");

// myObject is actually a duplicate of myObject, where all the fields are copied
// and the methods overridden. By default, Mockito silently records interactions.

myObject.foo(1);
verify(myObject).foo(anyInt());

// You can stub in a similar way, though doReturn is preferred over thenReturn
// to avoid calling the actual method in question.

doReturn(42).when(myObject).bar();
assertEquals(42, myObject.bar());
```

---

Barring that, this code is probably not working the way it looks like it should. `when`'s parameter is meaningless, and is sugar meant to hide that the mocked interaction is the most recent method call to a mock. For example:

```
SomeObject thisIsAMock = mock(SomeObject.class);
OtherObject notAMock = new OtherObject();

thisIsAMock.methodOne();
Mockito.when(notAMock.someOtherMethod()).thenReturn("bar");
// Because notAMock isn't a mock, Mockito can't see it, so the stubbed interaction
// is the call to methodOne above. Now methodOne will try to return "bar",
// even if it isn't supposed to return a String at all!
```

Mismatches like this can be easy sources of ClassCastException, InvalidUseOfMatchersException, and other bizarre errors. It's also possible that your real MyObject class takes a mock as a parameter, and that last interaction is with a mock that `someMethod` interacts with.

---

Your edit confirms my suspicions. As far as Java is concerned, it needs to evaluate the parameter to `when` before it can invoke `when`, so your test calls `someMethod` (real). Mockito can't see that—it can only take action when you interact with one of its mocks—so in your *first* example it sees zero interactions with mocks and thus it fails. In your *second* example your `someMethod` calls `doSomething`, which Mockito *can* see, so it returns the default value (null) and marks that as the most recent method call. Then the call to `when(null)` happens, Mockito ignores the parameter (null) and refers to the most recently called method (`doSomething`), and stubs that to return "bogus" from that point on.

You can see that by adding this assertion to your test, even though you never stubbed it explicitly:

```
assertEquals("bogus", mockAnotherObject.doSomething());
```

For an additional reference, I wrote [a separate SO answer on Mockito matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891), for which the implementation details might be useful. See steps 5 and 6 for an expanded view of a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I can confirm that myObject is not set to be a spy, and the real MyObject class does not take a mock as a parameter.  I agree that the code isn't doing what the person who wrote it probably intended.  I was just surprised it didn't fail.  Your comment about the mocked interaction being 'the most recent call to a mock' seems likely to be the explanation somehow, so I added the update to try to make the scenario complete and clear.  The real class does use another object, and it seems that when that other object is a mock I don't get the expected result.

Comment: @Shawn You're welcome! I updated my answer to annotate exactly what's going on in both of your edited-in examples.