# Can I mix Argument Captor and a regular matcher?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to verify a method with multiple parameter in Mockito, but need to capture only one argument, the others I need only a simple matcher. Is that possible?

For instance, if I have:

```
@Mock
private Map<K,V> mockedMap;
...
ArgumentCaptor<K> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(K.class);
verify(mockedMap).put(argument.capture(), any(V.class));
```

In this case do I need to write a captor for each argument in spite of the fact I need to capture only the first argument?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> In this case do I need to write a captor for each argument in spite of the fact I need to capture only the first argument?

[durron597's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32719372/1426891) is correct—you do not need to *capture* all arguments if you want to capture one of them. One point of clarification, though: a call to `ArgumentCaptor.capture()` counts as a Mockito matcher, and in Mockito if you use a *matcher* for any method argument [you do have to use a matcher for all arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

For a method `yourMock.yourMethod(int, int, int)` and an `ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intCaptor`:

```
/*  good: */  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(2, 3, 4);  // eq by default
/*  same: */  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(eq(2), eq(3), eq(4));

/*   BAD: */  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(intCaptor.capture(), 3, 4);
/* fixed: */  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(intCaptor.capture(), eq(3), eq(4));
```

These also work:

```
verify(yourMock).yourMethod(intCaptor.capture(), eq(5), otherIntCaptor.capture());
verify(yourMock).yourMethod(intCaptor.capture(), anyInt(), gt(9000));
```

Comment: This is really helpfull :)

Answer (score 6):

Of course it works. Why wouldn't it?

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.*;
import org.mockito.*;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MockitoTest {
  @Mock
  private Map<Integer, String> mockedMap;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testCaptor() {
    mockedMap.put(5, "Hello World!");
    ArgumentCaptor<Integer> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
    verify(mockedMap).put(argument.capture(), any(String.class));

    assertEquals(5L, argument.getValue().longValue());
  }
}
```

This works correctly and passes.

---

As an aside, you almost never want to mock data structures such as `List` and `Map`, because it's a giant pain to correctly mock all their behavior and most code won't be very happy if you, for example, add an element and then the element doesn't actually exist. In your case, it would probably be better to create a partial mock (using [`Mockito.spy`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16)) than an actual mock.