# Mockito.verify method contain boolean and argument captor

Tags: java, mockito

I don't know how can I use `Mockito.verify` in this case. How can I pass false to Mockito.verify? I try 2 different ways but it does not work.

```
public Sample someMethod(Sample s, boolean a){....}
@Test
public void test() {
...
verify(mock).someMethod(sampleCaptor.capture(), false));
verify(mock).someMethod(sampleCaptor.capture(), org.mockito.Matchers.eq(false)));
...
}
```

Comment: verify(mock).someMethod(sampleCaptor.capture(), false)); is working for me. I am using mockito-1.9.0.

Comment: Could you also post the declaration of `sampleCaptor`?

Comment: Please, provide us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what exactly goes wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have it right the second way:

```java
verify(mock).someMethod(
    sampleCaptor.capture(),
    ArgumentMatchers.eq(false));
```

When using matchers (including ArgumentCaptor.capture), you have to use a matcher for every value, because [matchers work via side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

If the above doesn't work, you may be misusing matchers earlier in the method. It is sometimes helpful to explicitly call `Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()` immediately before your call to `verify`, to ensure that there's nothing wrong with Mockito's internal state. (Additional information about how it "does not work", including a minimal reproducible example, may be helpful in solving your specific case.)

---

As Adam pointed out in the comments, `org.mockito.Matchers` (and `org.mockito.Mockito`) technically still work to get to `eq` and other matchers, but `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` is preferred (as used above). You can use `import static` to use them bare as `eq(false)` to hide the full package name.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I found the error that I made. I create a mock for someMethod but call true boolean, that's why it could not run.

Comment: The Matchers.eq is now deprecated. ArgumentMatchers.eq works the same way though.

Comment: @AdamWise I've updated the code and added a note.