# How to mock an entity using Mockito

Tags: mockito

I am using Mockito to mock Jersey Client API. I have a mock Response which returns me a `nullPointerException`.

This is what I have done so far

`when(invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(anyString(),MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))).thenReturn(response);`

Is there anyway to fix this.
Thanks,

Comment: Please post how you initialize your Mock object. We don't have enough information to help you now.

Comment: Hope this helps


clientConfig = mock(ClientConfiguration.class);
client = mock(Client.class);
clientConfig.createClient();


webTarget = mock(WebTarget.class);
clientConfig.createWebResource(URI);


response = mock(Response.class);


invocationBuilder = mock(Invocation.Builder.class);


statusType = mock(StatusType.class);

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Mockito matchers like that: They can only be used in the top level (here, as arguments to `post`). Furthermore, when you use one matcher, you have to use matchers for all arguments. I've written [more about matchers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work).

Matchers like `anyString` actually return `null`, and your NullPointerException likely comes from `Entity.entity` failing to accept a `null` value. (When you use matchers correctly in a `when` or `verify` statement, Mockito intercepts the call anyway, so the `null` doesn't interfere with anything.)

Instead, you'll need to return the response for everything and later use an [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to later ensure that the MediaType is APPLICATION_XML:

```
when(invocationBuilder.post(any())).thenReturn(response);
/* ... */
ArgumentCaptor<Entity> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
verify(invocation).post(captor.capture());
assertEquals(APPLICATION_XML, captor.getValue().getMediaType());
```

Or use [a custom `ArgumentMatcher<Entity>`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) to match:

```
ArgumentMatcher<Entity> isAnXmlEntity = new ArgumentMatcher<Entity>() {
  @Override public boolean matches(Object object) {
    if (!(entity instanceof Entity)) {
      return false;
    }
    Entity entity = (Entity) object;
    return entity.getMediaType() == APPLICATION_XML;
  }
};
when(invocationBuilder.post(argThat(isAnXmlEntity)).thenReturn(response);
```