# Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Tags: android, mockito

I need to verify a call for `handler.sendMessage(msg)`.

Code:

```
//This bundleImportStorage will send message to UI handler by passing message object
bundleImporter.bundleImportFromStorage(intent);

//In this line I am getting error
when(uiHandler.sendMessage(any(Message.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Exception details:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
  Invalid use of argument matchers!
  2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
  -> at com.fio.installmanager.nonui.com.bundleimport.TestBundleImport.testIntentExtras(TestBundleImport.java:69)

  This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
      //incorrect:
      someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
  When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
  For example:
      //correct:
      someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the message "2 matchers expected, 1 recorded", this can happens if `UiHandler.sendMessage(Message)` is a final method that delegates to a non-final two-argument method (often an overload of the same name). This is a problem because Mockito insists on each argument having exactly one matcher, if any matchers are used at all. Because final methods are invoked by [static dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch), and because Mockito works by dynamically overriding the mocked class, Mockito's first interaction is with a two-argument method that it assumes you're stubbing with a single matcher (explaining the otherwise-confusing error message).

If feasible, ensure that UiHandler and sendMessage are both public and non-final. If not, you may need to resort to [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) or [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to overwrite the `final` method at the bytecode level.

I've written more about Mockito internals, including the need for one matcher per argument, here on SO: [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891)