# How can I generically match only one argument in a method call using Mockito?

Tags: junit, arguments, mockito, matcher

I’m using JUnit 4.11 and Mockito 1.9.5.  How can I match all of the arguments in a method call except one, in which I don’t care if it’s generically matched?  Here is what I have

```
Mockito.verify(m_emailSvc).sendEmail(user.getAddress().getEmail(), fromEmail, subject, “template.vm", paramMap, (File) Matchers.any(File.class));
```

Notice that the last argument (of type java.io.File) is the one I’m trying to match generically.  Unfortunately, when this call is made, I get the run time exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf cannot be cast to java.io.File
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

What is the proper way to generically match only one argument?  If this requires an upgrade, that’s fine with me.

**Edit:**

In response to the answer given, here is the new exception that occurs upon running the JUnit test.  This may strike at the heart of my question — how do I combine a generic matcher with specific matchers.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
6 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**Edit 2**:
Ok, I wrapped everything in Matchers.eq calls …

```
            Mockito.verify(m_emailSvc).sendEmail(Matchers.eq(user.getAddress().getEmail()), 
                                                 Matchers.eq(fromEmail), 
                                                 Matchers.eq(pdCompletionSubject), 
                                                 Matchers.eq("send_pd_registration_completion.vm"), 
                                                 Matchers.eq(paramMap), 
                                                 Matchers.eq(Matchers.any(File.class)));
```

but still get the exception below

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
6 matchers expected, 7 recorded:
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
-> at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

    at org.mainco.springboard.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.testAddCEUCreditsCompleteTraining(TrainingSessionServiceDWRIT.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly: **The default action, without using Matchers, is equivalent to Matchers.eq.** To preserve that action while using other Matchers, including `any`, you can call `Matchers.eq` explicitly.

At this point, your call would look like this:

```
// N.B. Matchers is actually org.mockito.Matchers!
Mockito.verify(m_emailSvc).sendEmail(
    Matchers.eq(user.getAddress().getEmail()),
    Matchers.eq(fromEmail),
    Matchers.eq(subject),
    Matchers.eq("template.vm"),
    Matchers.eq(paramMap),
    Matchers.any(File.class));
```

---

However, the above is very unlikely to be responsible for the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf cannot be cast to java.io.File
```

Instead, this indicates that you're using the wrong Matchers class. You've imported `org.hamcrest.Matchers`, where calls to `Matchers.any(Class<T> clazz)` returns an instance of `org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf`. Instead, you want to call `org.mockito.Matchers.any(Class<T> clazz)`, which appears to return a `T` (to avoid your cast) but actually works via side effects.

---

You'll need to fix both problems (importing the correct Matchers class and also using one matcher per argument) to solve your problem. For more context on the difference between Hamcrest and Mockito matchers, and the need for one matcher per argument, see my [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

Comment: I changed to the Matcher class you suggested instead of Hamcrest and got the resulting exception (included as an edit to my question).

Comment: @Dave: It looks like you solved the second problem I listed in my answer, but not the first. Mockito is telling you `6 matchers expected, 2 recorded`; wrap the other 4 arguments in `Matchers.eq`.

Comment: OK. If you'd like, please post your updated code and make sure you're not wrapping any argument twice (e.g. `eq(any(...)))`) or using matchers at all outside of a stubbing/verification call. (Maybe as a new question!)