# ClassCastException in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following method for which I'm trying to write unit test using Mockito. I'm fairly new to Mockito and trying to catch up.

## Method to test

```
public synchronized String executeReadRequest(String url) throws Exception{

    String result = null;
    RestClient client = null;
    Resource res = null;
    logger.debug("Start executing GET request on "+url);

    try{
         client = getClient();
         res = client.resource(url);
         result = res.contentType(this.requestType).accept(this.responseType).get(String.class);
    }
    catch(Exception ioe){
        throw new Exception(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        res = null;
        client = null;
    }

    logger.info("GET request execution is over with result : "+result);
    return result;
}
```

The unit test with Mockito

```
@Test
public void testRestHandler() throws Exception {
    RestHandler handler = spy(new RestHandler());
    RestClient mockClient = Mockito.mock(RestClient.class,Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS); 
    Resource mockResource = Mockito.mock(Resource.class,Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

    doReturn(mockClient).when(handler).getClient();
    Mockito.when(mockClient.resource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockResource);

  //ClassCastException at the below line
    Mockito.when(mockResource.contentType(Mockito.anyString()).accept(Mockito.anyString()).get(Mockito.eq(String.class))).thenReturn("dummy read result");

    handler.setRequestType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    handler.setResponseType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    handler.executeReadRequest("abc");
}
```

But I'm getting a ClassCastException at the line

```
Mockito.when(mockResource.contentType(Mockito.anyString()).accept(Mockito.anyString()).get(Mockito.eq(String.class))).thenReturn("dummy read result");
```

Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4b441c4d cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This style of chaining during stubbing isn't correct:

```
Mockito.when(
    mockResource.contentType(Mockito.anyString())
        .accept(Mockito.anyString())
        .get(Mockito.eq(String.class)))
    .thenReturn("dummy read result");
```

Even though you've set the mocks to return deep stubs, [Matchers work via side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), so this line doesn't achieve what you think it does. All three matchers (`anyString`, `anyString`, `eq`) are evaluated during the call to `when`, and the way you have it your code is likely to throw `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` at the slightest provocation—including adding unrelated code or verifications later.

This means your problem *isn't* the use of `eq(String.class)`: It's that Mockito is trying to work the Class matcher in where it doesn't belong.

Instead, you'll need to stub specifically:

```
Mockito.when(mockResource.contentType(Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(mockResource);
Mockito.when(mockResource.accept(Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(mockResource);
Mockito.when(mockResource.get(Mockito.eq(String.class))) // or any(Class.class)
    .thenReturn("dummy read response");
```

Note that some of the difficulty here is that [Apache Wink](https://wink.apache.org/documentation/1.2.1/api/org/apache/wink/client/RestClient.html) uses the Builder pattern, which can be laborious in Mockito. (I've returned `mockResource` here, but you could imagine returning specific other Resource objects, at the expense of requiring them in exactly that order later.) A better way might be to [use a default Answer that returns `this` whenever possible](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2012/01/09/stubbing-builder-pattern-in-mockito/).

Answer (score -2):

Solved it by changing the get call to

```
get(Mockito.any(Class.class))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.