# Error: a *different* void method cannot be stubbed with a return value

Tags: java, mockito

When stubbing `ClassOne.methodOne`, I'm getting the following error message about stubbing a void method with a return value, even though `ClassOne.methodOne` is not void. The error seems to pertain to `ClassTwo.methodTwo`, even though I'm stubbing `ClassOne.methodOne`.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
`'methodTwo'` is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
***

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. The method you are trying to stub is *overloaded*. Make sure you are calling
   the right overloaded version.
2. Somewhere in your test you are stubbing *final methods*. Sorry, Mockito does not
   verify/stub final methods.
3. A spy is stubbed using `when(spy.foo()).then()` syntax. It is safer to stub
   spies with `doReturn|Throw()` family of methods. More in javadocs for
   Mockito.spy() method.
```

My code:

```
public class ClassOne {
  private ClassTwo classTwo;

  public boolean methodOne() {
    classTwo.methodTwo();
    return true;
  }
}
```

My test:

```
when(classOne.methodOne("some string")).thenReturn(true);
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This can happen when you try to stub a method that Mockito cannot override.** The way the syntax for `when` works, Mockito identifies *the most recent call it can detect* as the method call to stub. If Mockito cannot detect the method call you're stubbing, but can detect a call on a mock that happens within the actual implementation of the stubbed method, then it may mistake that call as the stubbing call. Thus, it thinks you are stubbing void method `ClassTwo.methodTwo` with a return value, and throws the exception.

```
/* 1 */  when(classOne.methodOne("some string")).thenReturn(true);
/* 2 */  when(              false              ).thenReturn(true);
/* 3 */  (    internal mockito stub object     ).thenReturn(true);
```

Normally, Mockito calls `classOne.methodOne`, which is an unstubbed method on a mock. Mockito's default implementation detects the call, records the invocation as the last-received invocation, and returns false. Then, in step 2 above, Mockito sees the call to `when`, marks that last invocation as a stub instead, and prepares for a call to `thenVerb`, which comes in step 3. *However, in this case, during step one, Mockito hasn't overridden `methodOne`, so it can't detect the call or record the invocation*. It actually calls `classOne.methodOne`, and if there are any interactions with a mock, those get recorded instead as if they were in the test above the `when` call. Step 2 proceeds as before, except that Mockito marks the wrong call for the stub, so  step 3 sees a call to `thenReturn` for the void method.

This can be even more troublesome if you use Matchers, because if there are the wrong number of Matchers on the [internal matcher stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), then you may get an InvalidUseOfMatchersException, even if the stubbing call in the test appears to use matchers correctly.

---

This problem crops up when Mockito cannot override the method you're stubbing. You'll need to check that the following is all true:

- The class should be non-`final`, and should not have [non-`public` parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331122/mockito-weird-package-scope-class-inheritance-issue).
- The method should be non-`static` and non-`final`.
- The instance should be a Mockito mock. Note that if it is created with `@InjectMocks`, it is a real implementation and not a mock; [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467685/1426891).
- As mentioned in the exception, when stubbing a spy, [use `doReturn`/`doAnswer`/`doThrow` syntax](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12), because otherwise you will call the spy's actual method from within the call to `when`.

Comment: Why can't Mockito overide `methodOne`? Is the issue in the question caused by `@InjectMocks`?  Looking at your checklist, `ClassOne` is non-final and has no parent (other than `Object`), and `methodOne` is non-static and non-final. So the only 2 items left which could explain the issue are `@InjectMocks` and stubbing a spy. The question doesn't seem to say how the mock was created.

Comment: @aro_tech: This question is a generalization of [another recent Mockito question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35372493/1426891), with a goal of a canonical question/answer pair as a dupe target. With the exact code listing in the question, InjectMocks is the likely reason as it was in the original linked question, but the misleading error could come from any of the listed reasons in the answer.

Comment: This helped me solve my problem with intermittent mocking failures. The class under test made a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` whose runnable called another method on the mock that was failing.