# Mockito and callback returning "Argument(s) are different!"

Tags: android, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm trying to use mockito on android. I want to use it with some callback.
Here my test :

```
public class LoginPresenterTest {


private User mUser = new User();

@Mock
private UsersRepository mUsersRepository;

@Mock
private LoginContract.View mLoginView;

/**
 * {@link ArgumentCaptor} is a powerful Mockito API to capture argument values and use them to
 * perform further actions or assertions on them.
 */
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<LoginUserCallback> mLoadLoginUserCallbackCaptor;

private LoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;

@Before
public void setupNotesPresenter() {
    // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the @Mock annotation. To
    // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    // Get a reference to the class under test
    mLoginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(mUsersRepository, mLoginView);

    // fixtures
    mUser.setFirstName("Von");
    mUser.setLastName("Miller");
    mUser.setUsername("von.miller@broncos.us");
    mUser.setPassword("Broncos50superBowlWinners");
}

@Test
public void onLoginFail_ShowFail() {

    // When try to login
    mLoginPresenter.login("von.miller@broncos.us", "notGoodPassword");


    // Callback is captured and invoked with stubbed user
    verify(mUsersRepository).login(eq(new User()), mLoadLoginUserCallbackCaptor.capture());
    mLoadLoginUserCallbackCaptor.getValue().onLoginComplete(eq(mUser));

    // The login progress is show
    verify(mLoginView).showLoginFailed(anyString());
}
```

But I got this error :

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mUsersRepository.login(
    ch.example.project.Model.User@a45f686,
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at example.ch.project.Login.LoginPresenterTest.onLoginFail_ShowFail(LoginPresenterTest.java:94)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
mUsersRepository.login(
    ch.example.project.Model.User@773bdcae,
    ch.example.project.Login.LoginPresenter$1@1844b009
);
```

Maybe the issue is that the second actual argument is ch.example.project.Login.LoginPresenter$1@1844b009 ?

I followed : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#5

Thank you for help =)

**Edit**

The method I try to test (LoginPresenter):

```
@Override
public void login(String email, String password) {

    mLoginView.showLoginInProgress();

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(email);
    user.setPassword(password);

    mUsersRepository.login(user, new UsersRepository.LoginUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLoginComplete(User loggedUser) {
            mLoginView.showLoginComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorAtAttempt(String message) {
            mLoginView.showLoginFailed(message);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
eq(new User())
```

When using `eq` (or not using matchers at all), Mockito compares arguments using the `equals` method of the instance passed in. Unless you've defined a flexible `equals` implementation for your User object, this is very likely to fail.

Consider using `isA(User.class)`, which will simply verify that the object `instanceof User`, or `any()` or `anyObject()` to skip matching the first parameter entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I delete eq() before my User, I got a new error :" org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at .Login.LoginPresenterTest.onLoginFail_ShowFail(LoginPresenterTest.java:94)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

Comment: @Xero: When you use Matchers, you need to use one Matcher (or Captor) per argument, for [implementation-specific reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). That's why I'm not suggesting removing just the `eq`, but instead replacing the expression with one of the three Matchers I listed (`isA`, `any`, or `anyObject`).

Comment: I tried isA, any and anyObject on User, but I got the same error. You don't think that the error is from the second parameter ?

Comment: I edited my post with the method I'm trying to test, It could help

Comment: I got your code running on my machine, reproduced the problem and applied Jeff fix - all works. You have another error in the code, but rest is fine.  
  
Are you sure this line:  
`verify(mUsersRepository).login(isA(User.class), mLoadLoginUserCallbackCaptor.capture());`
  
is still failing?  
  
Also you probably want to change your last verify to:   
`mLoadLoginUserCallbackCaptor.getValue().onErrorAtAttempt("error");`

Comment: Oh good, thank you, it was that. I understand more this tests now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am using mvp pattern with rxjava 2 and dagger 2, and was stuck on unit testing a presenter using Mockito. The code that gave me the "Argument(s) are different!” Error:

```
@Mock
ImageService imageService;

@Mock
MetadataResponse metadataResponse;

private String imageId = "123456789";

@Test
public void getImageMetadata() {
    when(imageService.getImageMetadata(imageId)).thenReturn(Observable.just(Response.success(metadataResponse)));

    presenter.getImageMetaData(imageId);
    verify(view).showImageData(new ImageData()));
}
```

Which throws error messages such as the following:

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted: Actual invocation has different
>   arguments: com.example.model.ImageData@5q3v861

Thanks to the answer from @Jeff Bowman, it worked after I changed this line

```
verify(view).showImageData(new ImageData()));
```

with

```
verify(view).showImageData(isA(ImageData.class));
```