# "Invalid use of argument matchers" but I use matchers only

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I get the error message:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>   -> at *.SegmentExportingTest.happyDay(SegmentExportingTest.java:37)
>   This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>   When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>   For example:
>   //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

but in reality I use only matchers in arguments of the method.

The next code is a source of the error above.

```
ConfigReader configReader = mock(ConfigReader.class);
    when(configReader.getSparkConfig())
            .thenReturn(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("app"));
    when(configReader.getHBaseConfiguration()).thenReturn(new Configuration());

    SparkProfilesReader sparkProfilesReader = mock(SparkProfilesReader.class);
    ProfileSegmentExporter profileSegmentExporter = mock(ProfileSegmentExporter.class);

    //--
    new SegmentExporting().process(configReader, sparkProfilesReader, profileSegmentExporter);
    //--

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(sparkProfilesReader, profileSegmentExporter);
    inOrder.verify(sparkProfilesReader).readProfiles(any(JavaSparkContext.class),
            refEq(configReader.getHBaseConfiguration()));
```

Comment: The problem was solved. I extracted configReader.getHBaseConfiguration() in the separate line and the issue was hided.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved in the comments:

> I extracted configReader.getHBaseConfiguration() in the separate line and the issue was hided.

Your specific problem is that *you're calling a mock method in the middle of setting up your matchers*.

---

The two lines that indicate the problem are these:

```
when(configReader.getHBaseConfiguration()).thenReturn(new Configuration());
// ...
inOrder.verify(sparkProfilesReader).readProfiles(any(JavaSparkContext.class),
    refEq(configReader.getHBaseConfiguration()));
```

As I wrote in [a previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), Mockito matchers work mostly via side-effects, so call order among Matcher methods and mock-object methods matters a lot to Mockito and its validation. The call to `configReader.getHBaseConfiguration()` is a call to a mock (as established in the first line) that happens after your call to `any(JavaSparkContext.class)`, which confuses Mockito into thinking you're verifying zero-arg method `getHBaseConfiguration` with one argument that `any` matches. That's why the error message says "0 matchers expected, 1 recorded": The 0 is for `getHBaseConfiguration` and the 1 is `any(JavaSparkContext.class)`.

To be safe, when using Mockito matchers, make sure the values passed to the matchers are all pre-calculated: They should all be constant literals, simple math expressions, or variables. Anything that involves a method call should be extracted to a local variable before stubbing/verifying begins.