# Using both mock and fake objects in junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Is it fine to use both mock objects and fake objects together in unit-testing code.

Example

```
when(computationHelper.someMethod()).thenReturn(stringGrid.writeCell(rowNum,colNum,value));
```

where computationHelper is mock object and stringGrid is my own implementation and a fake object.

Comment: It is fine but the whole idea of mocking is isolating a component from the chain of class dependencies and hence coupling a fake object with it doesn't seem right

Comment: There are no rules against it. I would make sure my mocked objects had `mock` in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, it is allowed to use a variety of [test doubles](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) including mocks, fakes, and stubs, all within the same test. As [ndrone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2980345/ndrone) mentioned in the comments, you may want to pick a naming system or convention to help you identify which of your dependencies are mocks or fakes, particularly to make it easier to help diagnose whether a test is failing due to a missing mock expectation or due to an actual system failure.

You may also consider using real implementations; after all, the decision to isolate your unit-under-test can be taken to excess, as one would hope you could trust the JRE's implementations or Mockito's implementations, and you shouldn't be tempted to mock or replace those. I tend to use real implementations when they are *fast, deterministic, and well-tested*—and when they are straightforward enough not to require deep dependency graphs themselves. (This takes a bit of judgment; I'd be tempted to use a real EmailAddressParser, for example, but maybe not a real FullStackRpcServer.)

---

One word of caution, though: You may want to extract the return value to a variable.

```
Result result = stringGrid.writeCell(rowNum,colNum,value);
when(computationHelper.someMethod()).thenReturn(someMethodResult);
```

This is for two reasons:

1. For newbies to Mockito, your original syntax may look like `writeCell` is called every time `someMethod` is called, where in reality that doesn't happen unless you write your own Answer. Extracting it to a variable makes it clear that Mockito will evaluate `writeCell` exactly once when you're setting up your `when` statement.
2. Though your syntax works fine when using a fake or a real implementation, if `stringGrid` were a mock, similar code may not work. This is because [Mockito relies heavily on side-effects and execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work), and so calling a mock in the middle of stubbing a method may cause hard-to-diagnose exceptions. As a rule, it's safer to ensure that every parameter within a call to `when` or `verify` is a local variable, constant, or literal (possibly within a Mockito matcher, as applicable); extracting here makes it easier to hold to that rule.