# Cannot use mocked function calls in parameters of verify: too many invocations

Tags: java, mockito

The setup is as follows:

```
//call doA a bunch of times, call doB once using some value that depends on doA()
verify(mockedThing).doB(eq(mockedThing.doA())); //removing eq() changes nothing
```

Obviously, `doA()` is configured to return some value, and `mockedThing` is indeed mocked. The result is: mockito complains that I call `doA` (Emphasis here: NOT `doB`!) too often, and that it expected it to be called only once!

The following change works:

```
int result = mockedThing.doA() 
verify(mockedThing).doB(eq(result));
```

My question is simple: what is going on here? Why is Mockito verifying the call to the *parameters* I pass to the function rather than the calls to the function itself?

Comment: What object/class are you trying to test here? You only seem to be calling methods on mocks here and no actual class

Comment: I have made a bare-bones implementation to simplify the question, highlighting the issue. The test is basically just some call to a real object's `doSomething()` which triggers the mock's `doA()` (more than once) and `doB(int)` (only once), functions. Particularly, `doSomething()` consists of two lines, minimally: `mockedThing.doA();` and  `mockedThing.doB(mockedThing.doA());`. This is sufficient to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: A lot of Mockito is based on the last-called function, and calls to mocks implicitly check state in ways that aren't compatible with the syntax you're trying to use. [I wrote a bit more on this answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, Mockito is actually stateful in unintuitive ways; many times the method stubbed or verified is simply the "last called method", mostly because syntax like `verify(foo).doA()` actually calls `doA` rather than passing a reflective reference to the method `doA` into Mockito. This simply isn't compatible with syntax that calls the same mock in the middle of stubbing or verification.

I've [written about this before with regard to Matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), which have the same problem during stubbing. Poking through the source code, you can see the same problem with verification, at least when calling a method on the same mock.

In short, verification is actually a three phase process:

1. Call `verify(mockedThing)`.
2. Call matchers, in order, if necessary. Do not call any methods on `mockedThing`.
3. Call the method that you're verifying on `mockedThing`, with actual parameter values if you're not using matchers, and dummy (ignored) parameter values if you are using matchers. Since Mockito keeps track of the matchers stack in the background, matcher methods can return `0` or `null` without Mockito thinking those are values to check against.

#### Under the covers

Calls to [`verify`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.0.52-beta/src/main/java/org/mockito/Mockito.java#L1718) actually just [set a flag and return the exact same mock](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.0.52-beta/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/MockitoCore.java#L85):

```
public <T> T verify(T mock, VerificationMode mode) {
  // [catch errors]
  mockingProgress.verificationStarted(new MockAwareVerificationMode(mock, mode));
  return mock;
}
```

Then, [inside the *handler* that handles all mock invocations](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.0.52-beta/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/handler/MockHandlerImpl.java#L76), Mockito starts verification on the first call to the mock that happens once verification is started:

```
public Object handle(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
  // [detect doAnswer stubbing]
  VerificationMode verificationMode = mockingProgress.pullVerificationMode();
  // [check Matcher state]

  // if verificationMode is not null then someone is doing verify()
  if (verificationMode != null) {
    // We need to check if verification was started on the correct mock
    // - see VerifyingWithAnExtraCallToADifferentMockTest (bug 138)
    if (((MockAwareVerificationMode) verificationMode).getMock() == invocation.getMock()) {
      VerificationDataImpl data = createVerificationData(invocationContainerImpl, invocationMatcher);
      verificationMode.verify(data);
      return null;
    } else {
      // this means there is an invocation on a different mock. Re-adding verification mode
      // - see VerifyingWithAnExtraCallToADifferentMockTest (bug 138)
      mockingProgress.verificationStarted(verificationMode);
    }
  }

  // [prepare invocation for stubbing]
}
```

Therefore, if you interact with the mock just to get a parameter value, Mockito is going to assume that you're actually calling the method to verify. Note that if the call was slightly different, like `verify(mockedThing).doB(eq(5), eq(mockedThing.doA()));` with the extra `eq(5)`, you'd get a different error message about misusing matchers—specifically because Mockito doesn't just think you're verifying `doA`, but that you somehow think `doA` takes an argument.

#### Consequences

Your code doesn't work:

```
// DOESN'T WORK
verify(mockedThing).doB(eq(mockedThing.doA()));
// BECAUSE IT BEHAVES THE SAME AS
verify(mockedThing).doA();
```

But extracting it does work:

```
// WORKS, though it makes an extra call to doA
Value value = mockedThing.doA();
verify(mockedThing).doB(eq(value));
```

And this also works, and shows off what's happening under the covers, **but don't ever write this in a real test**:

```
// WORKS BUT DON'T EVER ACTUALLY DO THIS
Value value = mockedThing.doA();
verify(mockedThing);
eq(value);
mockedThing.doB(8675309 /* dummy value ignored because of matcher */);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Bowman's answer helps explain what is going on.

> A lot of Mockito is based on the last-called function, and calls to mocks implicitly check state in ways that aren't compatible with the syntax you're trying to use. [I wrote a bit more on this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work) – Jeff Bowman yesterday

Comment: Glad this helped! Sorry I didn't have time to post an in-depth answer (I was on my phone); I added one with more details in case you're curious. Cheers!