# How to create custom matchers in Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito for unit testing. And there are many matchers like `anyString()`, `anyBoolean()` in Mockito. But suppose if I have a custom `enum` like

Enum LoginType.java

```
//LoginType.java
public enum LoginType {
    FACEBOOK,
    EMAIL,
    GOOGLE
}
```

In one of the method arguments I need to pass an instance of `LoginType`. How do I pass the argument without explicitly passing `LoginType.FACEBOOK` or `LoginType.GOOGLE`. Something like `anyString()`. Any hint in that direction will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `any` behavior, just calling `Matchers.any()` may be good enough on Java 8. That's when parameter type inference came out.

You might also choose `Matchers.any(LoginType.class)`, which has pure `any()` behavior in Mockito 1.x but will provide type checking in Mockito 2.0 and beyond. In either case, passing in the class literal will help Java get the type information you need for inference.

---

For related problems:

- If you have a generic type, the class literal isn`t enough either; you need to specify it as an explicit method parameter:

  ```
  Matchers.<YourContainer<YourType>>any();
  ```

  ...or extract to a static helper method, which you need to do instead of a constant or local variable because [Mockito matchers work via side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891):

  ```
  public static LoginType anyLoginType() {
    return Matchers.any();
  }
  ```
- Finally, for future readers who might be here to implement custom matching logic, look for `Matchers.argThat` or `MockitoHamcrest.argThat` to adapt a Hamcrest-style Matcher object into a Mockito method call.

Comment: Cheers for argThat!