# How to stub a method with a parameter that has specifics properties

Tags: java, mockito

How to stub a method with a parameter that has specifics properties ?

For example :

```
doReturn(true).when(object).method( 
    // an object that has a property prop1 equals to "myprop1"
    // and prop2 equals to "myprop2"
)
```

Comment: https://mrtnrbrts.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/custom-matchers-with-mockito/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's another way with something like hasProperty(), isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need either a custom Mockito matcher or a Hamcrest matcher for this problem, or a hybrid of the two. [The two work a little differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891), but you can use them together with adapters.

#### With Hamcrest

You'll need to use `Matchers.argThat` (Mockito 1.x) or `MockitoHamcrest.argThat` (Mockito 2.x) to adapt the Hamcrest [`hasProperty`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.html) matcher and combine it.

```
doReturn(true).when(object).method(
  argThat(allOf(hasProperty("prop1", eq("myProp1")),
                hasProperty("prop2", eq("myProp2"))))
)
```

Here, `argThat` adapts a Hamcrest matcher to work in Mockito, `allOf` ensures you're only matching objects that satisfy both conditions, `hasProperty` inspects the object, and `eq` (notably Hamcrest's `eq`, not Mockito's `eq`) compares string equality.

#### Without Hamcrest

Mockito no longer depends directly on Hamcrest as of Mockito v2.0 (in beta now), so you may want to do the same logic with Mockito's ArgumentMatcher class in a similar style.

```
doReturn(true).when(object).method(
  argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<YourObject>() {
    @Override public boolean matches(Object argument) {
      if (!(argument instanceof YourObject)) {
        return false;
      }
      YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) argument;
      return "myProp1".equals(yourObject.getProp1())
          && "myProp2".equals(yourObject.getProp2());
    }
  })
)
```

Naturally, this same custom matcher class technique works with Hamcrest too, but you might prefer the `hasProperty` technique above if you're sure you're working with Hamcrest.

#### Refactoring

One word of caution: Though you are welcome to save Matcher objects however you'd like (returned in a static helper method or saved in a field), the call to `argThat` [has side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891), so the call *must be made during the call to `method`*. In other words, save and reuse your `Matcher` or `ArgumentMatcher` instances if you want, but don't refactor out the call to `argThat` unless you do so *into a static method* so `argThat` still gets called at the right time.

```
// GOOD with Hamcrest's Matcher:
Matcher<YourObject> hasTwoProperties = (...)
doReturn(true).when(object).method(argThat(hasTwoProperties));

// GOOD with Mockito's ArgumentMatcher:
ArgumentMatcher<YourObject> hasTwoProperties = (...)
doReturn(true).when(object).method(argThat(hasTwoProperties));

// BAD because argThat is called early:
YourObject expectedObject = argThat(...);
doReturn(true).when(object).method(expectedObject);

// GOOD because argThat is called correctly within the method call:
static YourObject expectedObject() { return argThat(...); }
doReturn(true).when(object).method(expectedObject());
```