# define mockito when with multiple any arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to define `when` mockito method with multiple `any` arguments:

```
TestBedDaoClient testBedDaoClient = mock(TestBedDaoClient.class);
when(testBedDaoClient.addTestBed(anyString(), anyString(), any(VCloudConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(testBedPojoMockData);
```

In target test class:

```
TestBedPojo addedTestBedPojo = testBedDaoClient.addTestBed(testBedName, testBedDescription, vCloudConfiguration);
```

In DAO client:

```
public TestBedPojo addTestBed(String testBedName, String testBedDescription, VCloudConfiguration vCloudConfiguration){
     return testBedPojo;
}
```

I wanted to define `when` in such a way that it returns `testBedPojoMockData` with any values of arguments. But I am getting error: `Argument(s) are different!`

I even tried:

```
when(testBedDaoClient.addTestBed("test", "test", any(VCloudConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(testBedPojoMockData);
when(testBedDaoClient.addTestBed(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(testBedPojoMockData);
```

But no luck. How I can define this `when` so that it returns the mock data on any call?

Comment: Can you please paste the `addTestBed()` signature? Also, can you show us, how you define `testBedPojoMockData`? Which is the problematic line according to the exception?

Comment: TestBedPojo , I have setters and setters in TestBedPojo, and setting the mock data for TestBedPojo in TestBedPojoMockData class and getting TestBedPojo as return type from TestBedPojoMockData. TestBedPojo is the signature both for `addTestBed()` and `testBedPojoMockData`. Actually I want to get the mockdata on every call(ie: independent of value argument).

Comment: As said, can you edit your post and add the signature of the method you are trying to mock ?

Comment: Didn't you forget your RunWith annotation?

Comment: We need the method signature : public TestBedPojo  addTestBed( ....

Comment: "Arguments are different" is an error usually from `verify`. Does not mean that your `when` isn't working (when usually just returns null when arguments doesn't match). Also, I see no `verify`in your code examples...

Comment: Thanks @Tobb! `verify` was the issue.

Comment: Be careful, by the way, for your "I even tried": The first `when` mixes matcher arguments with non-matcher arguments. You have to stick with all-matchers or all-values for any particular `when` or `verify` invocation.

Comment: Yes! @JeffBowman , that I realize after multiple run. Is that a bug?

Comment: No, not quite a bug; it's a well-documented rule (see [Mockito JavaScript section 3's warning](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3)) that is a consequence of Matcher design and syntax. I wrote about those implementation details in a [separate SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

Answer (score 5):

The correct combination of `when` and `verify` should be used. It's failing on any other combination of argument in `addTestBed` method.

```
when(testBedDaoClient.addTestBed(anyString(), anyString(), any(VCloudConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(testBedPojoMockData);
//calling target method
verify(testBedDaoClient, times(1)).addTestBed(anyString(), anyString(), any(VCloudConfiguration.class));
```