# Use Mockito to match a null list of a specific type

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that takes a few parameters. One of them is a List of some class, and null is an acceptable value for this parameter.

```
public void doStuff(String string, @Nullable List<SomeClass> list) {
    ...
}
```

I want to write a test that uses Mockito to verify the method was called with null as a parameter. I tried using `isNull(List.class)`:

```
MyClass myClass = ...
verify(myClass).doStuff(any(String.class), isNull(List.class));
```

but this generates a warning:

> unchecked conversion
>   required: java.util.List<
>   com.package.SomeClass>
>   found:    java.util.List

I can see how to fix this warning in the event that the list is not null:

```
// this generates the same warning
verify(myClass).doStuff(any(String.class), any(List.class));

// this does not generate the warning
verify(myClass).doStuff(any(String.class), Matchers.anyListOf(SomeClass.class)));
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to combine these two approaches together. Or find an alternate approach that accomplishes what I am trying to do. (Other than suppressing the warning with an annotation)

Comment: Why would a `null` list ever be an acceptable parameter ?? What's the reason for not using an empty list instead ?

Comment: I agree it's far from an ideal design decision. The actual method is considerably more complicated and accepts a long list of optional parameters. Rather than forcing someone to create a dozen empty lists it was decided to let them pass null instead. Naturally it would have made more sense to have multiple methods or implement some kind of builder or factory, but it's an Android library and emphasis was placed on keeping the APK size and dex count low instead of usability. I would love to clean it up in the future, but for now it's what I have to work with.

Comment: But you are taking some time right now to resolve your problem anyway ! Why not using it to refactor this method instead of trying to make the mock working ?? I think that it's totally worth the time. And btw it's not a big deal to write `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `null` ?

Comment: It's an API method already used by multiple clients. I can't delete it without breaking applications that are already published. But I do want to write tests for it.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is to use an explicit generic method argument.

```
verify(myClass).doStuff(any(String.class), Matchers.<List<SomeClass>>isNull());
```

Additional notes:

- In practice, the warning isn't protecting you from anything; `null` is `null`, and with type erasure all of these forms will compile to the same bytecode anyway.
- Java 8 can infer generic types from method arguments, so `isNull()` is sufficient there without cleverness.
- Mockito 1.x calls the class `org.mockito.Matchers` whereas Mockito 2.x deprecates that class in favor of `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`. In both cases the matcher methods are visible through `org.mockito.Mockito`, but static-methods-via-inheritance is semantically weak and can cause those methods not to show up in IDEs.
- There's no way to specify `<List<SomeClass>>isNull()` without the `Matchers` as a static argument. What you *can* do, if you need to do this a lot, is to extract a local static method...

  ```
  private static List<SomeClass> nullSomeClassList() {
    return isNull();  // Return value types can be inferred before Java 8.
  }

  // elsewhere
  verify(myClass).doStuff(any(String.class), nullSomeClassList());
  ```

  ...but whatever you do, [don't extract to a field instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). The side effects are what matters here.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried this out, but it resulted in a similar problem. The code generated a build error, complaining that the method required a List<String> and it found an Object instead.

I tried typecasting the result of the matcher to List<String> and that resolved the build error, but now it still generates an unchecked conversion warning. This time it complains about converting Object to List<String>.