# Mockito 2 changes in any(Class) method

Tags: java, mockito

I've updated to Mockito 2.1 from version 1.9.

Now some of my tests fail. There seems to be a change in the `any(Bla.class)` method. Before this test was fine:

```
when(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(any(Expression.class),
     any(Comparable.class)))
    .thenReturn(predicate);
```

Now the expression `any(Expression.class)` is null.

Do I need to use another method to make it work again?
I got it working with `(Expression)any()` but that doesnt look right to me.

Comment: Please confirm that `criteriaBuilder` is a mocked object? Why would you care if `any()` returns a null value? It shouldn't be used in calling your implementation code anywhere, unless I've misinterpretted your question.

Comment: FYI there is some [changes in v2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-mockito-2) around the use if `any()` but I'm not sure it would affect the problem you are describing

Answer (score 8):

Drop the `Expression.class` and call `any` without parameters:

```
when(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(any(), any()))
    .thenReturn(predicate);
```

---

As of Mockito 2, `any(T.class)` changed meaning: Where before it meant "any reference including null, cast to the type `T` to avoid an explicit cast in Java 7 and previous", it changed to read "any instance of class `T`": Thus, `any(Foo.class)` would stop matching `null` during an upgrade from 1.x to 2.x.

`any()` without parameters still means "any reference including null", consistent across 1.x to 2.x, so calling `(Expression) any()` or `ArgumentMatchers.<Expression>any()` can restore the behavior you want. Because of the improved generic type inference rules in Java 8, you may also be able to call `any()` and have Java infer the type.

Don't worry about expressions like `any` returning `null`, by the way: That's [how Mockito matchers work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891). A separate stack tracks "how to match this argument", rather than returning a "special instance" or "special value"; this is necessary because Java is strongly-typed enough that there's no way to encode the idea "greater than 5" within the `int` that `gt(5)` returns. `0` and `null` are safe default values, so Mockito returns them while storing the concept of `any` or `gt(5)` in the corresponding position on the stack.

The NullPointerException is probably coming from your code receiving `null` (the default value for stubbed calls) where it was expecting to receive `predicate`.