# "Mockito 0 matchers expected, 3 recorded" - Why are 0 matchers expected?

Tags: android, mockito, matcher

This question has been asked before but the existing answers don't quite apply to my situation.

I'd like to test the `submitCode()` method:

```
public class VerificationCodeViewModel{

    //Input
    public final ObservableField<String> verificationCode           = new ObservableField<>();

    //Output
    public final ObservableField<String> requestError               = new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableBoolean loading                          = new ObservableBoolean();
    public final ObservableField<LoginCredentials> loginCredentials = new ObservableField<>();

    @NonNull private final Context context;
    @NonNull private final UnverifiedUser unverifiedUser;
    @NonNull private final CampaignRepository campaignRepository;
    @NonNull private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @NonNull private final VerificationCodeNavigator navigator;

    public VerificationCodeViewModel(@NonNull Context context,
                                     @NonNull UnverifiedUser unverifiedUser,
                                     @NonNull CampaignRepository campaignRepository,
                                     @NonNull AccountRepository accountRepository,
                                     @NonNull VerificationCodeNavigator navigator) {

        this.context = context;
        this.unverifiedUser = unverifiedUser;

        this.campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.navigator = navigator;
    }

    public void submitCode() {

        loading.set(true);

        String sourceCampaign = null;
        if (campaignRepository.getCampaign() != null) {
            sourceCampaign = campaignRepository.getCampaign().getSource();
        }

        this.accountRepository.verifyMobileNumber(
                this.unverifiedUser,
                this.verificationCode.get(),
                sourceCampaign,
                new AccountDataSource.VerifyMobileNumberCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationSuccess(UnverifiedUser.Entity entity) {
                        loading.set(false);
                        loginCredentials.set(createLoginCredentials());
                        navigator.finishActivity(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailure(@Nullable String message) {
                        loading.set(false);
                        requestError.set(message);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

I have the following test case:

```
public class VerificationCodeViewModelTests {

    private VerificationCodeViewModel viewModel;

    @Mock private Context context;

    @Mock private UnverifiedUser unverifiedUser;

    @Mock private CampaignRepository campaignRepository;

    @Mock private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Mock private VerificationCodeNavigator navigator;

    @Mock private ArgumentCaptor<AccountDataSource.VerifyMobileNumberCallback> verifyMobileNumberCallbackCaptor;


    @Before
    public void setupVerificationCodeViewModel(){

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        viewModel = new VerificationCodeViewModel(
                context,
                unverifiedUser,
                campaignRepository,
                accountRepository,
                mock(VerifyMobileNumberActivity.class)//navigator
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubmitCode(){

        viewModel.verificationCode.set(VERIFICATION_CODE);
        viewModel.submitCode();

        assertTrue(viewModel.loading.get());

        verify(accountRepository).verifyMobileNumber(
                eq(unverifiedUser),//line 132
                eq(VERIFICATION_CODE),//line 133
                eq(CAMPAIGN_SOURCE),//line 134
                verifyMobileNumberCallbackCaptor.capture());//line 135

        UnverifiedUser.Entity entity = mock(UnverifiedUser.Entity.class);
        when(entity.getId()).thenReturn(ENTITY_ID);

        verifyMobileNumberCallbackCaptor.getValue().onVerificationSuccess(entity);

        assertFalse(viewModel.loading.get());
        assertEquals(viewModel.loginCredentials.get().getUsername(),UNVERIFIED_USER_EMAIL);
        assertEquals(viewModel.loginCredentials.get().getPassword(),UNVERIFIED_USER_PASSWORD);

        verify(navigator).finishActivity(true);
    }
}
```

When I verify that the `accountRepository.verifyMobileNumber` is invoked, I get the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
>   -> at ...testSubmitCode(VerificationCodeViewModelTests.java:132) 
>   -> at ...testSubmitCode(VerificationCodeViewModelTests.java:133) 
>   -> at ...testSubmitCode(VerificationCodeViewModelTests.java:134)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
>
> at
>   ...VerificationCodeViewModelTests.testSubmitCode(VerificationCodeViewModelTests.java:135)

What I do not understand is why does it say 0 matches expected? Other answers suggest replacing `eq(..)` with `any(...)` or `isA(..)`. 
Firstly, I don't believe that's applicable because the error is that no matchers are expected in the first place;
and secondly, I've tried it and the issue persists.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain why 0 matchers are expected and how to fix this problem.

**Update**

The implementation of `AccountRepository.verifyMobileNumber()` is:

**AccountRepository.java**

```
public class AccountRepository implements AccountDataSource {
    @Override
    public void verifyMobileNumber(@NonNull UnverifiedUser unverifiedUser, 
                                   @NonNull String verificationCode, 
                                   @Nullable String sourceCampaign, 
                                   @NonNull VerifyMobileNumberCallback callback) {
        this.remoteSource.verifyMobileNumber(unverifiedUser, verificationCode, sourceCampaign, callback);
    }
}
```

**AccountRemoteDataSource.java**

```
public class AccountRemoteDataSource implements AccountDataSource {

    @Override
    public void verifyMobileNumber(@NonNull UnverifiedUser unverifiedUser,
                                   @NonNull String verificationCode,
                                   @Nullable String sourceCampaign,
                                   @NonNull final VerifyMobileNumberCallback callback) {

        accountService().verifyMobileNumber(/*params*/).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                try{
                    //parse response
                    callback.onVerificationSuccess(entity);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    callback.onVerificationFailure(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                callback.onVerificationFailure(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is in that line? Post the entire error please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I've included the full error message and marked the relevant lines in the code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and well-labeled source so far, but in addition, please post the implementation of `verifyMobileNumber`. There's a very good chance that it's `final`; both AccountRepository and `verifyMobileNumber` should be non-`final`. (I'm a bit surprised it says "3 matchers recorded" instead of "4 matchers recorded", but 0 expected is a pretty decent signal that you're not verifying what you think you are.)

Comment: @JeffBowman Thanks! I've included the implementation. `AccountRepository` is a `final` field in the `viewModel` (removing `final` did not fix the problem). `AccountRepository`,`remoteSource` and `verifyMobileNumber()` are all not `final`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahahaha, found it! You're using a `@Mock ArgumentCaptor` by mistake in the sixth annotated field of your tests file.

```
@Mock private ArgumentCaptor<AccountDataSource.VerifyMobileNumberCallback>
    verifyMobileNumberCallbackCaptor;
```

Mockito hasn't special-cased its own infrastructure, so it hasn't caught the fact that you're trying to mock Mockito itself. By calling the method `ArgumentCaptor.capture()` in the middle of the `verify` call, Mockito assumes that you're actually trying to verify the call to `capture`.

Despite its clever syntax, Mockito is really just a state machine, where the call to `verify(...)` starts a verification, each call to a matcher pushes a matcher description [onto an internal stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), and then the next call to a Mockito mock triggers the verification. Mockito sees three matchers on the argument matcher stack for the zero-arg call to `capture`. That's why there are 3 matchers recorded, and 0 expected.

Switch that annotation to [`@Captor`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Captor.html) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Facepalm! Ofcourse, it all makes sense now. Thank you so much for taking the time to spot that