# Whitebox invokeMethod with eq("string")

Tags: android, testing, mockito, powermock

I have the test

```
 Document document = spy(new Document());
    Whitebox.setInternalState(documentReceiverInteractor, "document", document);

    String text= "string";

    Whitebox.invokeMethod(documentReceiverInteractor, "saveFields", anyString(), eq(text), anyString(),
            anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString());

    verify(document).setText(text);
```

after startup, I get this error:

```
 Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
document.setText(
    <any string>
);
-> at ru.psbank.msb.dev.business.document.edit.receiver.DocumentReceiverInteractorTest.saveFields(DocumentReceiverInteractorTest.java:98)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
document.setText(
    null
);
```

`eq` works fine with primitives and there are no objects. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried to debug the test invocation? is null actually passed?

Comment: Why do you invoke methods with Matchers in the first place? What do you expect there to happen. `eq("text")` is not the String "text". Matchers are used in `verify`, `when`, etc. but not in actual method invocations. `anyString()` for example returns an empty String and not any String. `eq("text")` will probably return null when used in a direct invocation.

You are simply using Matchers in the wrong place. Remove the matchers from your method invocations and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(documentReceiverInteractor, "saveFields",
    anyString(), eq(text), anyString(),
    anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
```

This statement doesn't make sense. Calls to `anyString()` and so forth are *signals to Mockito* that *only make sense within calls to `when` and `verify`*. Their return values are `null`, `0`, `""`, or other dummy values, and [their side effects are to modify Mockito's internal state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891); they are not random or arbitrary values for testing, and do not have any special behavior for Whitebox.

(Under the hood, you are calling `setText` with the return value from `eq(text)`, which is `null`, and matching it against one of the calls to `anyString()` that you've accidentally added to the argument matcher stack.)

Instead, pick specific values:

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(documentReceiverInteractor, "saveFields",
    "string 1",
    text,
    "string 2",
    "string 3",
    "string 4",
    "string 5",
    "string 6");
```

...and rather than using [Whitebox](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.html), which is in Mockito's `internal` package `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection` and is [deleted in Mockito 2.2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/489), you should consider making the method call more visible (package-private if your test is in the same package, public if not). Your test is a consumer of your class, after all. If you choose to go that route, consider adding [`@VisibleForTesting`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) or some other documentation (like `/** Visible for testing. */`).