# Mock a method that returns a static variable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock the following line:

```
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : S3Objects.withPrefix(s3, s3URI.getBucket(), s3URI.getKey())) {
     // some code
}
```

How do I go about mocking S3Objects.withPrefix? As per AWS documentation, the return type of this function is a static S3Objects (which is basically an iterable over a bucket).

I currently try to mock it using the following code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({S3Objects.class})
public class TestMyMethod extends TestBase { 
      public void setup() {
            // setup other stuff and mock them
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(S3Objects.class);
            Mockito.when(S3Objects.withPrefix(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(any(S3Objects.class));
            //continue setting up other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
.thenReturn(any(S3Objects.class))  /* bad */
```

In Mockito syntax, including in PowerMockito, you can't use `any` in `thenVerb` or `doVerb` methods like `thenReturn`. `any` can only stand in for an argument during a `when` or `verify` call, and has [other special rules specific to Mockito argument matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). Mockito needs to know precisely which object you intend to return as part of `thenReturn`.

You'll need to create a `mock(S3Objects.class)` mock and make sure it returns a valid `Iterator<S3ObjectSummary>` when its `iterator()` method is called. I'd do this by creating a `List<S3ObjectSummary>` in your test and then delegate the `iterator` to it like this (untested code, but hopefully it works):

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(S3Objects.class);
S3Objects mockS3Objects = mock(S3Objects.class);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objectsToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
objectsToReturn.add(/* ... */);

when(mockS3Objects.iterator())
    .thenAnswer((invocation) -> objectsToReturn.iterator());

when(S3Objects.withPrefix(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mockS3Objects);
```