# Mockito Error more matchers than expected

Tags: java, mongodb, mockito

```java
    when(mongoCollection.updateOne(new Document("_id", anyString()), new Document("$set", new Document("_id", anyString()).append("funds", anyInt())), any(UpdateOptions.class)))
        .then(i -> fundsByAccount.put(i.getArgument(0), i.getArgument(2)));
```

I have this java code i take in 4 matchers, but only 3 is expected, the first `anyString()` call and the second should be same, i want to reuse it so that i'll be able to do this in only 3 matchers call.

[Code snippet and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5px1.png)

```java
    when(mongoCollection.updateOne(new Document("_id", anyString()), new Document("$set", any(Document.class).append("funds", anyInt())), any(UpdateOptions.class)))
        .then(i -> fundsByAccount.put(i.getArgument(0), i.getArgument(2)));
```

I tried this but again this takes in 4 matcher calls, i need some way to reuse already captured values

Comment: You can't use argument Matchers like that. They can only be passed to the method you are mocking -- use `any(Document.class)` and get the strings out of the Document instance.

Comment: You need to think about how you want Mockito to decide whether the `when` is applicable, when a call to `updateOne` occurs.  Is it enough to have `mongoCollection.updateOne(any(document.class), any(Document.class), any(UpdateOptions.class))`?  If so, then write that.  If not, you might have to use some more sophisticated matchers to detect whether the method was called with the right kinds of `Document`.

Comment: Mockito cannot "destructure" your arguments. Your method expects 3 arguments, so you have to use exactly 0 or 3 matchers (for the top-level arguments; you cannot supply arguments that are part real, part matchers).

Comment: You may find [Jeff Bowman's excellent self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512) useful if you're trying to understand how to use matchers.

Comment: @tgdavies ok that helped thanks man appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito cannot and will not "destructure" complex arguments for you. And it cannot match chained method calls (at least not in the way you expect). To set up stubs for a method call, you need to either provide 0 matchers or match exactly the number of formal parameters.

Your method has 3 parameters, so you need to pass 3 matchers:

```
when(mongoCollection.updateOne(any(Document.class), any(Document.class), any(Document.class)))
    .then(i -> fundsByAccount.put(i.getArgument(0), i.getArgument(2)));
```

If both calls are important, you can either create the mock with `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` (read the disclaimer in its JavaDoc!); or set up `updateOne` to return another mock:

```
final Appender appendMock = Mockito.mock(Appender.class); // I don't know your type, use the correct one
when(mongoCollection.updateOne(any(Document.class), any(Document.class), any(Document.class)))
        .thenReturn(appendMock);
when(appendMock.append("funds", anyInt()), any(UpdateOptions.class)))
        .thenAnswer(....);
```

If you need your method call to be only matched when it is called with specific instances, you can use the `Mockito#argThat` matcher:

```
Mockito.argThat(doc -> Objects.equals(doc.getKey(), "_id")),
Mockito.argThat(doc -> Objects.equals(doc.getKey(), "$set")
        && Objects.equals(doc.getValue().getKey(), "funds"));
```

But maybe you have less trouble if you implement the interface of `mongoCollection` in your own custom class, which can then hold the state in memory. This might be easier, especially if you mock this class in many different tests.