# Is it OK / good practice to put assertions inside Mockito.argThat?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Let's say you have a JUnit test with Mockito and you have an argThat matcher:

```
Mockito.argThat(obj -> {
  return "ok".equals(obj.getStuff()) ||
         "ok2".equals(obj.getStuff2()) ||
         "ok3".equals(obj.getStuff3()) ||
         "ok4".equals(obj.getStuff4());
});
```

But now when you run the test and it fails, it generically fails and it's hard to figure out what condition fails and you need to use debugger.

If I do this:

```
Mockito.argThat(processedNuMessage -> {
  Assert.assertEquals("ok", obj.getStuff());
  Assert.assertEquals("ok2", obj.getStuff2());
  Assert.assertEquals("ok3", obj.getStuff3());
  Assert.assertEquals("ok4", obj.getStuff4());
  return true;
});
```

Now I get much easier assertions to use. But if feels kinda wonky.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is *explicitly* marked as a bad practice in the [`ArgumentMatcher.matches` documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html#matches(T)), emphasis in the original:

> The method should **never** assert if the argument doesn't match. It should only return false.

This is important for a couple of reasons: First, if there are multiple calls to the method, one call may fail while another passes. By throwing in the argument matcher, Mockito will fail before it gets a chance to match other stubs. Also, Mockito trusts that it can call this function without side effects in methods like `when`:

```java
when(yourMock.yourMethod(anyInt(), argThat(new ThrowingMatcher()))).thenReturn(...);
// this next line will fail at stubbing time because of the previous line
when(yourMock.yourMethod(eq(6), argThat(new ThrowingMatcher()))).thenReturn(...);
```

In the second stub above, Mockito will call `yourMock.yourMethod` before calling `when`, so Mockito will try to [match a call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891) to `yourMethod(0, null)`. This will trigger your matcher, which will throw an exception due to the mismatch, preventing you from stubbing further. This mismatch is only an example: if you throw from within an ArgumentMatcher and violate the interface contract, Mockito isn't guaranteed to work.

If you want Mockito to fail faster or more clearly, you do have a few options:

- For stubbing time, you can use `thenAnswer`:

  ```java
  when(yourMock.yourMethod(/* user= */ any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    User user = invocation.getArgument(0);
    /* your asserts here */
    return yourReturnValue;
  });
  ```
- For verification time, you can use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

  ```java
  ArgumentCaptor<User> userCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);
  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(userCaptor.capture());
  User user = userCaptor.getValue();
  /* your asserts here */
  ```
- You can enable [Strictness](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#strict_mockito), which causes Mockito to fail on an unstubbed method call. This is more idiomatic than the older Mockito 1.x technique of using a throwing [default answer](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.2.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer,T...)).

A few notes:

- You might benefit from giving your User a reasonable `toString` representation for debugging. There are [helper libraries](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html) for this. [ArgumentMatcher](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.2.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) also documents that it uses its `toString` method when printing verifications and failed matches.
- Depending on how carefully you match your methods, you might still run into the stubbing problem described at the top. Switching to `doVerb` methods like `doReturn` or `doAnswer` help, as the call to `doVerb` precedes the call to your mock so Mockito can deactivate stubbed behavior.
- Though *Hamcrest* matchers offers an appealing-looking [`describeMismatch`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html#describeMismatch(java.lang.Object,%20org.hamcrest.Description)), this typically has not been valuable in Mockito because Mockito's invocation matching algorithm makes it more difficult to reason about when a call is *missing* versus when a call is *mismatched*. It might still be a good solution for you, but you'd have to invoke the Matcher manually using one of the above techniques rather than just calling [MockitoHamcrest.argThat](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)).

Comment: argument captors worked best for me. exactly what i was missing