# Mock static java and kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, static, mockito

I have a static class that I want to mock, I can do this successfully in java. But when I convert to kotlin and tests now fail with the error

```
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here: -> at TestTest.testWrapperStatic$lambda$0(TestTest.kt:19)
```

Any ideas on what is different when mocking static in kotlin?

Class to mock,

```
object TextUtilsWrapper {
    @JvmStatic
    fun createFromParcel(p: Parcel): CharSequence {
        return TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(p)
    }
}
```

Passing Java test case,

```
public class TestTest extends BaseMockingUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testWrapperStatic() {
        Parcel parcel = Mockito.mock(Parcel.class);

        final MockedStatic<TextUtilsWrapper> textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic = mockStatic(
                TextUtilsWrapper.class);
        textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic.when(
                () -> TextUtilsWrapper.createFromParcel(any())).thenReturn("hello");

        assertThat(TextUtilsWrapper.createFromParcel(parcel), is("hello"));
    }
}
```

Failing kotlin test case,

```
class TestTest : BaseMockingUnitTest() {
    @Test
    fun testWrapperStatic() {
        val parcel = Mockito.mock(Parcel::class.java)
        val textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(
            TextUtilsWrapper::class.java
        )
        textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic.`when`<Any> { createFromParcel(ArgumentMatchers.any()) }
            .thenReturn("hello")
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(createFromParcel(parcel), Matchers.`is`("hello"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that Kotlin adds null-checking code.
Check the decompiled source of your test class:

```java
public final class TextUtilsWrapperTest {
  @Test
  public final void testWrapperStatic() {
    Parcel parcel = (Parcel)Mockito.mock(Parcel.class);
    MockedStatic textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TextUtilsWrapper.class);
    textUtilsWrapperMockedStatic.when(TextUtilsWrapperTest::testWrapperStatic$lambda$0)
      .thenReturn("hello");
    Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(parcel, "parcel");
    Assertions.assertEquals("hello", TextUtilsWrapper.createFromParcel(parcel));
  }
  
  private static final void testWrapperStatic$lambda$0() {
    Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(ArgumentMatchers.any(), "any()");
    TextUtilsWrapper.createFromParcel((Parcel)ArgumentMatchers.any());
  }
}
```

The expected event sequence is:

- argument matcher is called and registered on stack
- mocked method call is intercepted and `MockMethodAdvice.handleStatic` is called
- this calls `ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl.pullLocalizedMatchers` and clears the matchers stack.

See: [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work)

Unfortunately, `Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue` throws a NullPointerExeption, as `ArgumentMatchers.any()` returnes null.

This NPE is silently ignored, but mocked method is not called, and thus handleStatic is not called - the matchers stack is not cleared.

The matchers stack is checked upon `MockedStaticImpl.when` call, and the `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` is reported.

To solve, use `mockito-kotlin` provided argument matchers:

```
/** Matches any object, excluding nulls. */
inline fun <reified T : Any> any(): T {
    return ArgumentMatchers.any(T::class.java) ?: createInstance()
}

/** Matches anything, including nulls. */
inline fun <reified T : Any> anyOrNull(): T {
    return ArgumentMatchers.any<T>() ?: createInstance()
}
```