# Mockito.eq(1) sending value as 0 to the function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am testing the below method using the JUnit and Mockito framework.

```
public Business updateBusiness(BusinessRequest businessRequest, Long businessId) {
        String fileURL = fileStorageService.uploadFileToStorage(businessRequest.getFile(), businessRequest.getEmail());
        Business business = Business.builder()
                .businessId(businessId)
                .businessName(businessRequest.getBusinessName())
                .email(businessRequest.getEmail())
                .fileURL(fileURL)
                .status(BusinessStatus.PENDING)
                .category(categoryService.getCategoryByID(businessRequest.getCategoryId()))
                .description(businessRequest.getDescription())
                .build();
        businessRepository.save(business);
        return business;
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateBusiness() {
        BusinessRequest mockedBusinessRequest = BusinessRequest.builder()
                .email("testEmail@dal.ca")
                .businessName("TestBusinessName")
                .role(Role.PARTNER)
                .file(new MockMultipartFile("TestName", new byte[]{anyByte()}))
                .description("TestBusinessDescription")
                .categoryId(1L)
                .build();
        Business actualBusiness = businessServiceMock.updateBusiness(mockedBusinessRequest, Mockito.eq(1L));
        Assertions.assertEquals(mockedBusiness, actualBusiness);
}
```

Here the parameter passed as `businessId=1` but the value which coming in the method parameter variable is 0.

[Expected vs Actual Business Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u5zt.png)

How can I pass the value 1L to the method and also please tell the reason why even though I am passing 1L to the method it is changing to 0L.

Comment: Is the `businessServiceMock` a mock as the name suggests or a real instance of your service you want to test? If a mock then what is your class under test? If a real instance then you should mock the `fileStorageService`, `categoryService` and `businessRepository` set expectations against interactions with these mocks and assert the result

Comment: @Julian It was a mock of the original class. The expectations were also set. There was one problem with `new MockMultipartFile("TestName", new byte[]{anyByte()})` which I replaced with `byte[] arr = new byte[2];` and `new MockMultipartFile("TestName", arr)`

Comment: `any` methods like `anyByte` [can't work as return values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). They only work within method calls that you use in Mockito's `when` and `verify` calls, not in a Builder or constructor (or anything else) you actually call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step through debug you can see that Mockito.eq(1L) is trying to compare the Object wanted in the Equals class (probably null) to your 1L. The return value will be 0 for false. You should be able to pass 1L directly into your function.

Comment: Thanks! 
`Business actualBusiness = businessServiceMock.updateBusiness(mockedBusinessRequest, 1L);` Works

Comment: Glad I could help. I highly recommend debugging in Eclipse or whatever IDE you like to use. There are some great tutorials on how to use debugging on YouTube (I recommend Coding with John). Debugging lets you step directly into Mockito.eq(1L) to see what it's doing. Happy coding!